# Program hangs when closing serial port connection

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am reading data through a USB connection as a serial port with the PL2303 driver. It returns successfully when doing an `open` and when I set they TTY options and non blocking. When I try to close the connection, it hangs. In this state it reads "�" instead of characters.

I can connect to the device perfectly fine with cutecom. Here is the strange part:

1. If I first connect to the device via cutecom (a serial monitor), my program will connect and close perfectly fine every time afterwards. It reads the characters as I expect them to be read. (No �).
2. If I disconnect and reconnect the hardware, my program will hang again until I run cutecom.

Since it works after I use cutecom, it makes me think that I am missing something in my initial connection, or connection settings. Here's what I use to connect:

```
baud_rate = 38400;
fd =  open (device_path, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY );
```

In my `set_tty_options` function:

```
struct termios tty_options;

memset (&tty_options, 0, sizeof(tty_options));
tcgetattr (fd, &tty_options);

cfsetispeed(&tty_options, baud_rate);                         // set baud rate
tty_options.c_cflag = (tty_options.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;   // 8 bit msgs
tty_options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);                      // enable reading

tty_options.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);                    // shut off parity
tty_options.c_cflag |= parity;
tty_options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
tty_options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty_options) != 0) 
{
  printf("error %d from tcsetattr\n", errno);
  return TTY_ERROR;
}
```

In `set_blocking` function:

```
if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
{
  printf("error %d from tggetattr", errno);
  return FAILURE;
}

// 0 or 1 byte is enough to return from read
tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = should_block ? 1 : 0; 
tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) 
{
  printf("error %d setting term attributes", errno);
  return FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: I see 2 problems with your code. First is that `set_tty_options` function does not seem to fully initialize the `tty_options` structure. That could explain the "my program works if I run X first, but hangs/fails if run solo." That's the classic symptom of a program that does not properly or fully initialize its environment.  Second, that `set_blocking` function is bogus for canonical input.  `c_cc[VMIN]` and `c_cc[VTIME]` should only be used for **non-canonical** (aka raw) input. For a non-blocking `read()` of canonical input, use `fcntl()` to set that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. I figured this out by basically copying and pasting parts from [cutecom's](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cutecom/develop) source code.

1. When opening...

   ```
   int fd, n;
   fd = open (device_path, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

   ... error check fd ...

   n = fcntl(ail_info->ail_serial_fd, F_GETFL, 0);
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, n & ~O_NDELAY);
   ```
2. You cannot set the baud rate as I was doing. You have to use the defined `B38400`;

   `baud = B38400;`
3. Then, I added wallyk's answer.

   `tty_settings.c_lflag = 0;`

**Edit:** As per sawdust comment, I found a better way to set this to raw input.

```
tty_options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
```

And it works.

Comment: *"Then, I added wallyk's answer. tty_settings.c_lflag = 0;"* -- You still have not properly configured the serial port.  What is `c_oflag` set to?  Note that hard assignment to `termios` struct members is not recommended per POSIX.  You should call `tcgetattr()`, and then enable or disable each attribute field (as you do for `c_cflag`).  See [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/serial.html).  You are using POSIX calls, so follow their rules.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add `| O_SYNC` to the open flags to insist on synchronous i/o.  I doubt that is causing a problem though.

However, I think you want to ignore the break signal, which is reported as a NUL character like you are getting:

```
tty_settings.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // ignore break signal
```

Also, you want to be sure the input processing is completely turned off, so that receipt of a backspace, ^C, ^\, etc. aren't triggering any reaction:

```
tty_settings.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                         // no canonical processing
```

It looks like you are already using [my set_blocking() function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6947758/198536), so that should be okay.