# How to do a protocol for SerialPort with error check?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a device, which send me messages like this [CommandID][Data][Data][CRC]. If CRC not equal i will skip this command, because i know the command lenght. But what i have to do if any byte will lose in transmission?

Comment: You do not want to toss the entire message.  See the accepted answer for  fixed-length messages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177947/identification-of-packets-in-a-byte-stream  For variable-length messages, there is probably a start or sync byte that has to be hunted.

Comment: The protocol is not good enough to protect you from lost bytes.  It requires at least a unique start byte so that you can resynchronize.  And a ACK/NAK style handshake so you can tell the transmitter to resend the message.  You'll have to implement a handler for the ErrorReceived event and put an end to it when you get a SerialError.Overrun or RXOver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CRC check will fail. And you must query again. I'm preferring to query 3-5 times before failing. Hardware unstable and very good chanel/device can fail.

Comment: Device don't send me command by request from PC. It send me command by external interrupt

Comment: Nothing different. You harvest bytes and when it completes transmission - calculate CRC. If you have error - discard it and wait for next one.