# c# saving COMport data to file

Tags: c#, serial-port, uart, rs

I am trying to send float data from STM32 board to computer via UART.
Im sending float data via UART as 4 frames - **4x8bits**. I have already made a function that converts those frames back to float.

My question is what should I do to stack like 1000 floats into array so I can later use it - outside of Handler.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort com = new SerialPort("Com3");

        com.BaudRate = 9600;
        com.Parity = Parity.None;
        com.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        com.DataBits = 8;
        com.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        com.RtsEnable = true;

        com.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(RxHandler);
        com.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        com.Close();
    }

    private static void RxHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        int bytes = sp.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        sp.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(ToFloat(new byte[] { buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3] }));
    }

    static float ToFloat(byte[] input)
    {
        byte[] fArray = new[] { input[0], input[1], input[2], input[3] };
        return BitConverter.ToSingle(fArray, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an instance of a collection (e.g. List) to store the received data. `List<Single> list = new List<Single>();` and in RxHandler `list.Add(ToFloat(....) );`

Comment: How do I refer to "list" when in  RxHandler 
Error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.list'

Comment: You need to impose somekind of protocol (i.e. message frame with integrity check) on this data link.  Your current code appears to use nothing for maintaining message framing.  E.G. lose a byte, and you start to convert the misaligned data into garbage float values.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177947/identification-of-packets-in-a-byte-stream for one scheme

Comment: Sorry, because you use static methods it must be defined static (inside class `Program` in front of `static Main`: static List<Single> list = new List<Single>();

Comment: If you want to write (human readable) the list to file after reading all values, put `File.WriteAllLines(filename, list.Select(p => p.ToString()));`  after `com.Close();`

Comment: @H.G. Sandhagen
I have created <byte>list as you told me. How do I access list elements when I need i.e. use method like ToFloat in my code?

Comment: See answer below. I added some code to your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code parts I added to save the floats into a file:

```
class Program 
{
    private static List<float> list = new List<float>();
    static void Main() {
        // see your code
        // ......
        com.Close();

        // Write list to file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("data.txt", list.Select(p => p.ToString()));
        // convert list to array
        float[] floatArray = list.ToArray();
    }

    private static void RxHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
        // see your code
        // ......
        sp.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);

        // store float in variable
        float f = ToFloat(new byte[] { buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3] }));
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        // add float to list
        list.Add(f);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is saving your floats' bytes on disk after validating them as such (i.e., as System.Single values) thru your existing ToFloat method, you could use [File.WriteAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) for instance.

If you'd like to save them as a human-readable representation, I guess you'll want to rely on [Single.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f71z6k0c(v=vs.110).aspx) before using, say, [File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Well, generally I'm generally planning to put my floats to array, then using them in order to create plot.

Comment: @Jejh Ok, maybe I got confused in which problem you're actually trying to solve beyond your question title, "c# saving COMport data to file" then.

Comment: For now I want to save my data to file