# Parsing continuous incoming byte array from serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have an incoming byte array in real-time that has the following format:

Header : 3 bytes

message: 10 bytes

Header : 3 bytes

message: 10 bytes

and so on

The problem is it is a continuous stream that I can not predict when the header comes as I could start reading incoming bytes at a portion of the message or header. So I would appreciate it if someone could assist me in how to trap a header and then stay in sync using dataReceived event.

Edit: I tried using a counter for checking each incoming byte as a header, then set the threshold to trigger after the payload is received.

1. Set Incoming threshold trigger to 1 byte
2. Check first, second headers
3. Get the payload if headers are detected and set the incoming threshold trigger to the payload.
4. Parse payload, set threshold again to 1 byte.

Although it is not bad, it is not reliable with each incoming frames unlike software like [serialplot](https://hackaday.io/project/5334-serialplot-realtime-plotting-software)

```cs
    private void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                byte data = 0;
                if (_syncCounter < 3)
                {
                    data = (byte)_serialPort.ReadByte();
                }
                switch (_syncCounter)
                {
                    case 0: // First Byte in Header
                        _syncCounter = data == (byte)0xAA ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0;
                        break;
                    case 1: // Second Byte in Header
                        _syncCounter = data == (byte)0xBB ? (byte)2 : (byte)0;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // Payload
                        _syncCounter = data == (byte)data ? (byte)3 : (byte)0;
                        if (_syncCounter == 3)
                        {
                            _serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = data;
                            _payload = data;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        // Packet
                        var packet = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0x00, _payload).ToArray();
                        byte[] fieldBytes;
                        float fieldFloat;
                        _serialPort.Read(packet, 0, _payload);
                        if (packet.Length < _payload)
                        {
                            _serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
                            _syncCounter = 0;
                            _payload = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (_isFirstPayload)
                            {
                                _syncCounter = 0;
                                _payload = 0;
                                _isFirstPayload = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            for (uint i = 0; i <= (_payload-1); i += 4)
                            {
                                fieldBytes = Slice(packet, i, i+4);
                                fieldFloat = ReadSingleBigEndian(fieldBytes, 0);
                                if (fieldFloat < 0)
                                    fieldFloat = 0;
                                _sb.Append(fieldFloat.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                                _sb.Append(",");
                            }
                            IncomingFrame.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            {
                                IncomingFrame.Text = ByteArrayToString(packet);
                                if (_sb.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    _sb.Remove(_sb.Length - 1, 1);
                                    FloatFields.Text = _sb.ToString();
                                }
                                _sb.Clear();
                                _serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
                                _syncCounter = 0;
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                }


 }
```

The problem is, sometimes I receive the header as part of the payload although, from the code I wrote, it should be filtered before reading the payload.

I checked the same response using serialplot and it is syncing meaning the hardware is sending data as expected and parsed correctly.

Comment: What does the header look like?

Comment: … also, do you know the range of values the message may contain?

Comment: It's not *"parsing"*, but rather a lexical scan.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177947/identification-of-packets-in-a-byte-stream/16180135#16180135 for ideas.

Comment: @madreflection, the header is 0xAA,0xBB and 1 Byte Payload (0x40)

Comment: @rfmodulator It is sending 4 bytes for each channel, these bytes represent 32-bit float which I can convert using bitConverter

Comment: I'd suggest you make an producer getting all data from serial port and put to a queue. A consumer parsing existing data.