I can't get all bytes printed on the screen as hex, even though I print them using a loop with a fixed number of times
I'm trying to write a LDS-02 driver for unix. Here is the documentation.
With the header and the size, one full packet is 47 bytes long.
Using termios, I read 94 (2 times 47) bytes, then I read and jump over each byte until I get the header (0x54) + size (0x2c) combo. Then I print the next 47 bytes (including 0x54 and 0x2c). But each line is less than that, with always a different number of bytes printed.
How is it possible ?
How can I fix it so I get all the data each time ?
Here is the code I've written so far:
/*
    This is based on the tutorial presented in this blog article:

    https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/operating-systems/linux/linux-serial-ports-using-c-cpp/
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include <fcntl.h> // Contains file controls like O_RDWR
#include <errno.h> // Error integer and strerror() function
#include <termios.h> // Contains POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <unistd.h> // write(), read(), close()

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int serial_port = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    if (serial_port < 0) {
        printf("Error %i from open: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    struct termios tty;
    if(tcgetattr(serial_port, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; //no parity
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; //only one stop bit
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;     //8 bits per byte
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // Disable RTS/CTS hardware flow control
    tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; // Turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines (CLOCAL = 1)
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; //disable cannonical mode
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; // Disable echo
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHOE; // Disable erasure
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHONL; // Disable new-line echo
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ISIG; // Disable interpretation of INTR, QUIT and SUSP
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // Turn off s/w flow ctrl
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL); // Disable any special handling of received bytes
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;    // Since the lidar is always sending stuff, we don't need any timeout
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 94;     // reading byte by byte
    cfsetspeed(&tty, B115200); // setting baud rate to 115200bits/s

    //no data will be sent, but just in case
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // Prevent special interpretation of output bytes (e.g. newline chars)
    tty.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR; // Prevent conversion of newline to carriage return/line feed

    // Save tty settings, also checking for error
    if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    //reading stuff
    unsigned char read_buf[94]; //a two packet-sized buffer
    int num_bytes;
    while(1){
        num_bytes = read(serial_port, &read_buf, 94); //reading, num_bytes is negative if error
        if (num_bytes < 0) {
            printf("Error reading: %s", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        if(true/*char_are_signed*/){
            for(size_t i = 0; i<94; i++){
                read_buf[i] = read_buf[i];
            }
        }
        size_t i = 0;
        while(!(read_buf[i] == 0x54 && read_buf[i+1] == 0x2c)){i++;}
        while(i<47){printf("%x ", read_buf[i]); i++;}
        printf("\n");
    }
}


You need to be aware that read might return before the full amount of data was read. You might need to read multile times before you get a full packet. You also need to check that you do not read beyond the end of your buffer in case you don't find 0x54, 0x27 in the buffer. "Then I print the next 47 bytes (including 0x54 and 0x2c). But each line is less than that, with always a different number of bytes printed." No, you don't print the next 47 bytes. You just loop until i==47. The second half of that buffer is never touched.

read_buf[i] = read_buf[i]; That is rather useless.

Did you run your code in debugger to verify that you received a packet successfully? Or check how many bytes you receive in a single call to read?


Why are you reading 2*47 Bytes?
Why Shouldn't the Packet start at the start of the communication.
You are not reading the next 47Bytes from when you find the magic numbers, you are printing 47B from the start of the buffer. If the packet starts in the middle of the received data  it will print less than the full 47Bytes


Your termios configuration has a potential bug. Before setting tty.c_cflag |= CS8;, the existing size-attribute needs to cleared using tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;.  The read() request should always return with the requested 94 bytes since VMIN=94 and VTIME=0, but regardless the return code should be checked for this expected count. Why is there a mix of coding styles? Did you copy code from somewhere and then added stuff you wrote?

@Leonard "Why Shouldn't the Packet start at the start of the communication." - Because the sending and receiving programs are not necessarily synchronized. Even if you do manage to start each end simultaneously, there's no guarantee that message synchronization is maintained, e.g. noise causes bad/dropped bytes. The OP has the right idea for a more robust/reliable connection (by scanning for the start sentinels of a message) than what you suggest, but it's a buggy implementation.

"With the header and the size, one full packet is 47 bytes long" - After you fix these bugs, you need to be aware that you may still not have a correct message. You have raw data (rather than text), so your scan of the buffer may have landed on data instead of the actual start of a message. An additional test that is needed for message validation involves the CRC byte at the end of the packet. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177947/identification-of-packets-in-a-byte-stream/16180135#16180135
