# Byte Order of Serial communication to Arduino

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to write a C++ application to send a 64bit word to an Arduino.

I used termios using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c)

The problem i am having is the byes are arriving at the arduino in least significant byte first.

ie

if a use (where serialword is a uint64_t)

```
write(fp,(const void*)&serialWord, 8);
```

the least significant bytes arrive at the arduino first.

this is not the behavior i was wanted, is there a way to get the most significant byes to arrive first? Or is it best to brake the serialword into bytes and send byte by byte?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have anything against swaping bytes before sending them?

Comment: You may wish to look into [`htonl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) and friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the endianess of the CPU's involved are different you will need to reverse the order of bytes before you send them or after your receive them. In this case I would recommend reversing them before you send them just to save CPU cycles on the Arduino. The simplest way using the C++ Standard Library is with [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) as shown in the following example

```
#include <cstdint>  // uint64_t (example only)
#include <iostream> // cout (example only)
#include <algorithm>  // std::reverse

int main()
{
    uint64_t value = 0x1122334455667788;

    std::cout << "Before: " << std::hex << value << std::endl;

    // swap the bytes
    std::reverse(
        reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value),
        reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value) + sizeof(value));

    std::cout << "After: " << std::hex << value << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs the following:

> Before: 1122334455667788
>   After: 8877665544332211