# Incorrect serial port input/output

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am attempting to activate a serial port on the Beaglebone black and have connected the TX to the RX. I wrote a test program. In it, I setup my serial port to 1152000 baud and no parity according to help I found at [how to open, read, and write from serial port in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c). Below is my main function:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *portname = "/dev/ttyO4";

    int fd = open (portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf ("error %d opening %s: %s", errno, portname, strerror (errno));
        return 0;
    }

    set_interface_attribs (fd, BAUD_RATE, 0);
    set_blocking (fd, 0);

    while (true)
    {
        write (fd, "Hello!\n", 7);
        char buf [100];
        int n = read (fd, buf, sizeof buf);
        std::cout << buf;
        std::cout.flush();
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I read something on the serial port RX, but it isn't hello, it is "ù¶" instead. Can someone tell me why this is happening??

Kind regards

Cornel

Comment: How is BAUDRATEBAUD_RATE defined? To clarify, (I believe) it can't just be any number - it has to be a baud rate constant, like `B115200`.

Comment: Why do you write tag [c] but source is C++?

Comment: BAUD_RATE is defined #define BAUD_RATE B1152000

Comment: Is the receiving end also setup with the same line parameters? Also, does the board/serial line/receiver support 1152K baud?

Comment: you have serial connection established. can you try sending litterals or just integers and see how the device is reading them . it can be an encoding problem .i.e you need to send the string in it is HEX equivalent.

Comment: Getting short strings with lots of bits turned on is a strong selector for setting the baudrate too high.  Pretty important too that your program can detect these kind of mishaps, you'll get a framing error from the serial port.

Comment: Changing the Baud rate to something lower and increasing the size of the string still gives nonsensical readings. It must have something to do with the port, because regardless of the string I send, I still get pretty much the same reading with a bit of variation?

Comment: Is your constant really B1152000? RS232 only supports a baud rate of 115200 not 1152000.

Comment: right now it is B9600, and same results

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: yes, I am using a single serial port for sending and receiving, so it is setup the same.