# Linux C Serial Program Freezes

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, arduino, beagleboard

I'm working on a small Linux server (Ubuntu Server 13.04 running on a Beagleboard xM ARM computer) that will be communicating between a laptop wirelessly and an Arduino.  The issue I seem to be having is regarding the communication between the Arduino and the Beagleboard.  The program will run just fine for a certain amount of time, ~30 seconds or so, then it will halt.  The program will stay running but the port apparently freezes.

The program I'm running is currently just a test program that will sweep a servo over a certain range.  The code for the functions used to set up the ports was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c).

My program code is as follows, with exception of the code found in the separate thread:

```
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <termios.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

   ...

   int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
        cout << "TestIO running...\n";
        char* portname = "/dev/ttyACM0";
        // Open serial port
        int fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);

        // Return error if port cannot be opened
        if (fd < 0)
        {
                cout << "error " << errno << " opening " <<  portname << ": " << strerror (errno) << "\n";
                return -1;
        }

        set_interface_attribs (fd, B9600, 0);   // set speed to 9600 bps, 8n1 (no parity)
        set_blocking (fd, 0);                   // set no blocking

        // Read from serial port
        //char inputBuffer[64];
        //int inputLength = read(fd, inputBuffer, sizeof inputBuffer);

        double output = 575;
        char outputString[255];
        char outputLength;
        int incrimentor = 1;
        char inChar;
        for(;;) {
                if (output >= 675 )
                        incrimentor = -1;
                else if (output <= 375)
                        incrimentor = 1;
                output += incrimentor;

                // Sweep wheels on car, set drive motor to 0
                outputLength = sprintf(outputString, "%0.2f", output);
                write(fd, outputString, outputLength);
                write(fd, ",", 1);
                write(fd, "0", 1);
                write(fd, "\n", 1);

                cout << outputString << "\n";

                // Sleep thread for 5000 uS (5 ms)
                usleep(5000);
        }
        close(fd);
        return 0;
}
```

On a slightly different note, when the program freezes I must force it to quit the code to close the port is never reached and thus I cannot run the program again to test it.  I'm curious if anyone might know how to close a serial port through a Linux command run in the terminal.

Thanks!

Comment: It takes ~1ms to output 1 char at 9600 baud.  You are sleeping for 5ms.  How many characters are you outputting every 5ms?  What flow control are you using?

Comment: That's a good point, currently I'm sending six every loop, in the future I will be sending eight plus.  However I tried delaying 10ms between loops, and this still ended in the same result.  I didn't actually time it, but I think it may have run a little longer.  This led me to believe there was a datatype being overflowed, but I looked and couldn't find one.  As for flow control I'm not currently using any, the line is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Referring your second issues on how to quit the hanging program:

Adding tests for the return value to all system calls is a good idea in general!

Be aware that `read()`/`write()` do not necessarily read in/write out as much data as the were told to.

Also `read()`/`write()` return if the process received a signal.

Here in particular add testing the result to the calls that might block (`write()`):

```
ssize_t writen(int fd, char * buffer, size_t size)
{
  ssize_t written_total = 0;
  ssize_t written = 0;

  while  (outputLength > written_total)
  {
    written = write(fd, buffer + written_total, size - written_total);
    if (-1 == written)
    {
      if (EINTR == errno)
      {
        /* interupted by signal -> break and leave */
        break;
      }
      elseif ((EAGAIN == errno) || (EWOULDBLOCK == errno))
      {
        continue; /* try again */
      }

      /* another error occured -> log, break and leave */

      break;
    }

    written_total += written;
  }

  if (outputLength > written_total)
  {
    if (-1 = written)
    {
      /* handle error */
    }
    else
    {
      /* notify of interruption */
    }
  }
  else
  {
    /* log succesfully transmission of all data */
  }

  return written_total;
}

int main()
{
  ...

  do
  {
    if (outputLength != writen(fd, outputString, outputLength))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "writen(fd, outputString, outputLength) failed");
      break;
    }

    if (1 != writen(fd, ",", 1))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "writen(fd, ",", 1)) failed");
      break;
    }

    if (1 != writen(fd, "0", 1))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "writen(fd, "0", 1)) failed");
      break;
    }

    if (1 != writen(fd, "\n", 1))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "writen(fd, "\n", 1)) failed");
      break;
    }
  } while (0);

  if (-1 == close(fd))
  {
    perror("close() failed");
  }

  ...
}
```

Note that the program also needs to have a signal handler registered (for `SIGUSR1` for example) that does nothing, but "eating" the signal.

Then from the command line you could easily un-block the program by doing:

```
$ kill <program-pid> -SIGUSR1
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Seems to be working well, I'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep, so thanks! This will save me a ton of time now.