# Getting Callerid from serial port with Conexant USB CX93010 modem?

Tags: c#, serial-port, modem

I have a C# code but it doesn't takes a CallerID from dial up modem connected to USB port when I connect line to phone. It gets CallerID but in program run and in reading line I have just RING nothing else.

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : XtraForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    SerialPort sp ;
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        sp = new SerialPort(textEdit1.Text);
        sp.NewLine = "\r\n";
        sp.Parity = Parity.None;
        sp.DataBits = 8;
        sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        sp.DtrEnable = true;
        sp.WriteBufferSize = 1024;

        sp.Open();
        sp.WriteLine("AT+VCID=1");
        sp.RtsEnable = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    void sp_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Close();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        memoEdit1.Text += "\n" + sp.ReadExisting();
    }

    private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Close();
    }
```

Comment: does your modem support receiving caller ID (FSK decoding)?

Comment: We expect users to post code that works, demonstrates the issue and is free of fluff. Your code is full of commented peices of code. Clean that up first.

Comment: Yes in manual it is writing that it is supporting Caller id detection Conexant USB CX93010 ACF Modem

Comment: @Manish - `AT+VCID=?` returns `(0-2)`, so yes the modem supports CallerID.

Comment: This modems are wired I just run AT+VCID=1 and modem reported callerId flawlessly but after few day it stopped working. A French guy did some investigation on this modem but they don't solve my problem.
https://www.domoticz.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33161

Comment: Another one did some experiment on Conexant and USR usb modems here (this one also didn't solve the problem):

https://superuser.com/a/1499229/398785

Answer (score 1):

When your modem supports caller id then make use of AT+CLIP=1. This will cause unsolicited +CLIP messages to be displayed when the modem is called.

The +CLIP unsolicited messages are usually formulated as follows:

```
+CLIP: <number>,<type>,,,,<cli validity>
```

Where `<number>` is a string containing the number in a format defined by `<type>`. `<type>` of address octet which for example for international numbers is 145. `<cli validity>` determines whether the number was withheld etc.

Comment: +VCID=1 could potentially solve your problems. It’s always good to track down an AT reference guide for your modem module. They are usually very useful on picking up on module specialities.

Answer (score 1):

Conexant USB CX93010 ACF Modem don't have FSK protocol

Comment: It does support FSK (actually most of dialup data modem work based on FSK). If you have any reference for it please mention that!
I think it should be related to timing or data length

Comment: I also shoud mention some lines may based on DTMF And It work with fsk mutiolation but about the DTMF I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting the code below based on some testing I was doing with the Conexant USB CX93010. The code below is in C (rather than C#) and runs on Linux (rather than Windows). But it should provide a good baseline for a C# program.

The code is based on another [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38318768/608639) written by Sawdust, and it has test results from the program.

You can also find a comprehensive AT command set for Conexant modems at [http://www.arcelect.com](http://www.arcelect.com/IML56_modem_AT_commands.pdf). It is dated from 2001, but it has more AT commands for the modems than I found elsewhere on the web.

---

Here is the code.

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DISPLAY_STRING 1

int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed)
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfmakeraw (&tty);
    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void write_command(int fd, const void* cmd, size_t len)
{
    if (len == ~(size_t)0)
        len = strlen((const char*)cmd);

    printf("Send %d: %s\n", (int)len, (const char*)cmd);

    int wlen = write(fd, cmd, len);

    if (wlen != len) {
        printf("Error from write: %d, %d\n", wlen, errno);
    }
    tcdrain(fd);    /* delay for output */
}

void read_response(int fd)
{
    char buf[256];
    int rlen = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);

    if (rlen > 0) {
#ifdef DISPLAY_STRING
        buf[rlen] = 0;
        printf("Read %d: \"%s\"\n", rlen, buf);
#else /* display hex */
        unsigned char *p;
        printf("Read %d:", rlen);
        for (p = buf; rlen-- > 0; p++)
            printf(" 0x%x", *p);
        printf("\n");
#endif
    } else if (rlen < 0) {
        printf("Error from read: %d: %s\n", rlen, strerror(errno));
    } else {  /* rlen == 0 */
        printf("Timeout from read\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fd;
    const char portname[] = "/dev/ttyACM0";

    fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error opening %s: %s\n", portname, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    /*baudrate 115200, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit */
    set_interface_attribs(fd, B115200);

    write_command(fd, "ATZ\r", 4); /* Reset */

    read_response(fd);

    write_command(fd, "ATE0\r", -1);  /* Echo off */

    read_response(fd);

    write_command(fd, "AT+VCID=?\r", -1);  /* Query CallerID caps */

    read_response(fd);

    write_command(fd, "AT+CLIP=?\r", -1);  /* Query CallerID caps */

    read_response(fd);

    write_command(fd, "AT+VCID=1\r", -1);  /* Set CallerID */

    read_response(fd);

    printf("Entering loop, CTRL+C to break...\n\n");

    while (1)
    {
        read_response(fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here are the test results using a cell phone. I changed the name and phone number; other wise it is the exact output of the program.

```
$ sudo ./modem.exe
Send 4: ATZ
Read 6: "
OK
"
Send 5: ATE0
Read 11: "ATE0
OK
"
Send 10: AT+VCID=?
Read 15: "
(0-2)

OK
"
Send 10: AT+CLIP=?
Read 9: "
ERROR
"
Send 10: AT+VCID=1
Read 6: "
OK
"

Entering loop, CTRL+C to break...

Read 8: "
RING
"
Read 67: "
DATE = 0214
TIME = 2116
NMBR = 2025551212
NAME = JANE DOE
"
Read 8: "
RING
"
Read 67: "
DATE = 0214
TIME = 2116
NMBR = 2025551212
NAME = JANE DOE
"
Read 8: "
RING
"
Read 8: "
RING
"
Read 8: "
RING
"
```

---

Also, you can send an `AT+GSR` to get the real modem revision instead of what Windows provides (which appears to be a little inaccurate):

```
Send 7: AT+GMR
Read 44: "AT+GMR
+GMR: CX93001-EIS_V0.2013-V92

OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You must set `Country of Installation` to `B5` by `AT+GCI=B5` I got it after a three weeks of investigations (It may defer in your country it can be 00 or B4 or B5 but B5 for works for most of land lines):

   [image]
2. Then enable CID reporting by `AT+VCID=1` or `AT+VCID=2` as it said in [manual](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf5/115/11410/1140976-conexant/cx93010.pdf?80a0b6308045e408c52fac12cf9f7514&take=binary):
   [image]
3. And then it works flawlessly:
   [image]

And this is my working code based on yours:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CIDResolver
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SerialPort sp;
        private void Connect_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sp = new SerialPort(textEdit1.Text);
            sp.BaudRate = 11500;
            sp.NewLine = "\r\n";

            sp.Open();

            sp.WriteLine("AT+GCI=B5"); // can be 00 or B4 or B5
            sp.WriteLine("AT+VCID=1");

            sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler((object _s, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs _e) =>
            {
                string newData = sp.ReadExisting();
                consoleOut.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                    // Running on the UI thread
                    consoleOut.Text += newData+ "\r\n";
                });
            });
        }


        private void disConnectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sp.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed_1(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            sp.Close();
        }
    }
}
```