# Using sleep() when reading from a serial port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am writing an application to read data from `/dev/ttyUSB0`. 
I found it necessary to call `sleep` before calling `read` in the while loop so that I get the entire line at once. Otherwise, sometimes I get part of the line and the rest in the next iteration.

Do I have to package my data with a header containing the length of the string being sent over? Or is there a better way?

```
    while(1) {
            usleep(10000);

            unsigned char buf[80];
            int rdlen;
            ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &rdlen);
            if (rdlen > 0) {
                    rdlen = read(fd, buf, rdlen);
            }
            if (rdlen > 0) {
            ...     

    }
```

Comment: Poll, read whatever is in the buffer, append to result.

Comment: Serial ports are inherently character devices. Any notion of "packet" or "line" you will have to implement yourself.

Comment: Using any sleep function will crap the performance.

Comment: By *"line"* do you actually mean a line of ASCII text terminated by a '\n', or a message packet of binary data?  For the former you would need to configure the serial terminal for canonical mode.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682995/reading-from-serial-port-in-c-breaks-up-lines/28689567#28689567  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224496/working-with-linux-serial-port-in-c-not-able-to-get-full-data/41252962#41252962  You fail to properly document your question with your initialization code.

Comment: I meant a line of null terminated ASCII text. I will update the question with my initialization code.

Comment: If you're receiving an ASCII NUL as the line terminator, then *termios* can be configured to treat the NUL as the EOL character.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586137/stop-on-newline-when-using-read/36588517#36588517

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to simply deal with receiving partial lines, have your code reading the data figure out when you have a complete line if that is important.

something like (not tested at all):

```
char buffer[1000];
size_t offset = 0;
while(1 ){
int len = read(fd, buffer+offset,(unsigned)(sizeof(buffer)-offset));
if(!strchr(buffer+offset, '\n')){
/* no end-of-line */
offset +=len;
}
else
{
/* deal with complete line */
offset = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: strchr needs NUL-terminated char array, something that is not guaranteed here.