# Canonical Mode Linux Serial Port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, termios

The Termios man pages (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) for canonical mode state:

> Input is made available line by line.  An input line is available
>            when one of the line delimiters is typed (NL, EOL, EOL2; or EOF at
>            the start of line).  Except in the case of EOF, the line delimiter
>            is included in the buffer returned by read(2).

My question is: when a piece of hardware outputs data to be canonical compliant - is it putting the 0xD0xA (CRLF) bytes at the beginning of the transmission line to tell the read() function that data is ready to be read?

I've not thought about this a lot before and have defaulted (potentially erroneously) to thinking that the 0xD0xA is at the end of the transmission line.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Is that ok? I was told not to post 2 questions in 1 thread.

Comment: It wasn't a criticism, just the background.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is it putting the 0xD0xA (CRLF) bytes at the beginning of the transmission line to tell the read() function that data is ready to be read?

Your question has essentially already been answered by [my last comment to you in your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116151/find-carriage-return-line-feed-in-c-char-array#comment100758958_57116151).
Apparently you don't believe the **man** page or me, and are also unclear what "line delimiter", line termination, and EOL mean.

The *"serial port"* or *"hardware"* has no concept of a *"beginning"* or an *"end"* of the *"transmission line"*.  It's all just payload data to the U[S]ART.
Line termination only has context when using termios in canonical mode to read the serial terminal buffer.
See [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/%7Erubini/docs/serial/serial.html) to understand how removed your userspace code is from the hardware.

Linux uses the newline character, or linefeed which has ASCII code 0x0A, as the line terminator, as clearly stated in the **man** page (which you have quoted).
Termios allows the definition of additional end-of-line characters, i.e. VEOL and VEOL2 for serial terminals.
Each and every occurrence of a line delimiter character can and will cause a (pending) canonical **read()** to return.
The line delimiter character will be the last character returned in the buffer, unless the user buffer is too small to contain the entire line.

The character defined for EOF, i.e. **VEOF** which defaults to the ASCII code 0x04 for EOT, is handled slightly different by termios.
The receipt of the EOF character causes a (pending) canonical **read()** to return just like a line delimiter character, but the EOF character is not stored in the returned buffer.
Hence, when the EOF is preceded by a line delimiter, **read()** will have a return code of zero, an actual empty line!

If you're such a Doubting Thomas, then you should cross-connect a pair of USB-RS232 adapters together, and test what happens when reading from a serial terminal using termios.
Use a terminal emulator program such as **minicom** on the first serial terminal to enter data, and use the following C program to see the canonical reads on the other serial terminal.

```
#define SERIALTERMINAL      "/dev/ttyUSB1"
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed)
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

    tty.c_cflag |= CLOCAL | CREAD;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     /* only need 1 stop bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no hardware flowcontrol */

    tty.c_lflag |= ICANON | ISIG;  /* canonical input */
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHOE | ECHONL | IEXTEN);

    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNCR;  /* preserve carriage return */
    tty.c_iflag &= ~INPCK;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(INLCR | ICRNL | IUCLC | IMAXBEL);
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);   /* no SW flowcontrol */

    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    tty.c_cc[VEOL] = 0;
    tty.c_cc[VEOL2] = 0;
    tty.c_cc[VEOF] = 0x04;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    char *portname = SERIALTERMINAL;
    int fd;
    int wlen;

    fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error opening %s: %s\n", portname, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    /*baudrate 115200, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit */
    set_interface_attribs(fd, B115200);

    /* simple output */
    wlen = write(fd, "Hello!\n", 7);
    if (wlen != 7) {
        printf("Error from write: %d, %d\n", wlen, errno);
    }
    tcdrain(fd);    /* delay for output */


    /* simple canonical input */
    do {
        unsigned char buf[83];
        unsigned char *p;
        int rdlen;

        rdlen = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
        if (rdlen > 0) {
            buf[rdlen] = 0;
            printf("Read %d:", rdlen);
            /* first display as hex numbers then ASCII */
            for (p = buf; rdlen-- > 0; p++) {
                printf(" 0x%x", *p);
                if (*p < ' ')
                    *p = '.';   /* replace any control chars */
            }
            printf("\n    \"%s\"\n\n", buf);
        } else if (rdlen < 0) {
            printf("Error from read: %d: %s\n", rdlen, strerror(errno));
        } else {  /* rdlen == 0 */
            printf("Nothing read. EOF?\n");
        }               
        /* repeat read */
    } while (1);
}
```

---

Note that the program does not strip out '\r' characters (i.e. attribute IGNCR is cleared), but carriage return is not defined as a line delimiter either.
Hence carriage returns in this termios configuration have no special meaning, and are passed through just like any printable character.

So typing (the equivalent of) `ABCDEFG^M^J` is read as:

```
Read 9: 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0x45 0x46 0x47 0xd 0xa
    "ABCDEFG.."
```

`123^Mabc^J` is read as:

```
Read 8: 0x31 0x32 0x33 0xd 0x61 0x62 0x63 0xa
    "123.abc."
```

An alternate termios configuration could strip out the carriage returns or treat the carriage returns as a line delimiter.

Comment: My application is receiving a long series of 0x0 values for no apparent reason. Now, my initial understanding of read() in canonical mode was that the only byte that would cause read() to return was '\n' or 0xA and for this reason could not figure out where all of these '\0' values where coming from. But, now that you describe VEOL and VEOL2, this sheds some light on my situation. Because, VEOL2 is set to 0, this means that when the GPS hardware i'm using sends a '\0' read() is cycling. Would the hardware be sending this series of '\0' as a break condition?

Comment: *"Because, VEOL2 is set to 0, this means ..."* -- Your reasoning is wrong.  If you used the sample code provided, then you would learn that *"VEOL2 is set to 0"* means it is disabled.  It is impossible (using termios) to define \0 or NUL as a line delimiter. *"Would the hardware ..."* -- Once again you try to go off topic.  You persist in posting tangential questions (to your salient issue), and then try to steer comments to your problem.  This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: The Termios man page explains:  "VEOL   (0, NUL) Additional end-of-line character (EOL).  Recognized when ICANON is set. VEOL2  (not in POSIX; 0, NUL) Yet another end-of-line character (EOL2).  Recognized when ICANON is set." I don't see reference to 0 meaning it is turned off. The description/symptoms of my problem have been changing with the testing i'm doing. Do you suggest I post 'tangential questions' in another question thread?

Comment: Marking this as answered because this helped.

Comment: i  used this  code for reading data from a serial peripheral(sensor). I get data like this :                              line 1 : 20 bytes data ,  line 2 : 30 bytes data , line 3 : 52 bytes data....and so on line 7 : 60 bytes data , every time it is printing this line x : <n> bytes data is due to this line of code :  printf("\n  \"%s\"\n\n", buf),I  hve commneted the byte portion currently.   this line 1 - 7 line repeats with different data based on sensor . As i understand it is the termios doing this data split into 7 lines. Is it possible to get the whole chunk in a buf? how?

Comment: @Raulp *"I used this code ..."* --  Seems like you used the program without studying its description.  Your questions are unanswerable because (a) you haven't specified what this *"serial peripheral (sensor)"* is, (b) you haven't described the data received other than some byte counts, (c) the program was tested for its intended purpose, i.e. read short ***lines of text***, (d) you seem to be misquoting what the program displays, and (e) if you have a (new) problem then post a new question

Comment: @sawdust Posting a new thread will be duplicate and i cant paste all logs here so pasting it in pastebin . its a location sensor data log. I pasted the data here : https://pastebin.com/YUjzRBM7 . you see here  read line 72 or read line 70 till read 53 comes as one print on the terminal. You can see  its coming periodically.What I want is to retrieve thw whole burst of message from line read 72/70 to read 53 in every burst. I have pasted my  /dev/device  settings at the end of the pastebin. Please Let me know how in code i can achieve this or some settings of   tty.c_lflag .

Comment: @Raulp -- Comments are not to be used for extended discussion, and certainly not for solving a new problem. If you want an answer, then post a question.