# How to setup GDB for kernel debug to view serial port activity?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb

Good day all!
I have an issue in code that I cannot find.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239782/select-and-read-times-out-on-serial-port-read-yet-previous-write-succeeds)

Is it possible to setup GDB to see what the UART is getting in incoming serial data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to modify UART driver for Linux kernel and inside of this driver dump the incoming data. The GDB works in user space but you need to do this on the lower level - in UART driver. GDB has no access to registers of the physical device as the UART is.

Comment: Great idea ... but beyond my capability.