# Can I read and write via one (USB to SerialPort converter) through NULL modem cable to another (SerialPort to USB) on same computer?

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port, usb

I am writing a Serial Port class in C++.

To test this:
I want to hook up a USB to SerialPort(RS-232) converter on one USB.
Connect a NULL modem cable from that SerialPort(RS-232) to Serial to USB convert to another USB on the same computer.

Comment: Yes you can, I do that often.  Even suggested it in an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152937/canonical-mode-linux-serial-port/57155531#57155531

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was able to hook up 2 (USB to RS-232 converts) to the same computer and connection between them was established via NULL modem cable.

Then I had to look in the DeviceManager ports to see what com ports I can use.

Ran a 2 instances of the program(client, server) communication worked well.

Comment: Yes you certainly can, although many developers will find it easier to use a pure-software solution such as `com0com`, unless they actually need the timing that comes with real USB transfers and conversion to UART signalling.