# How are virtual COM/Serial ports managed by operating system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, serial-port, pyserial

I'm currenty working on an interface between arduino and raspberry pi. The arduino is connected via usb cable to the Rasbperry Pi. The Arduino has an LED connected to a digital Pin that may be turned on and off by sending specified bytes over the USB serial connection. The Raspberry Pi then runs the following python script:

```py
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=115200, timeout=.1)
time.sleep(2)
start = time.time()

for _ in range(10):
    arduino.write(bytes([0x58])) //Turns LED on (on Arduino)
    print(time.time()-start,'on')
    time.sleep(.5)
    arduino.write(bytes([0x18])) //Turns LED off (on Arduino)
    print(time.time()-start,'off')
    time.sleep(.5)

arduino.write(spam_the_COM_port) # will let the arduino start sending 
                                 # infinite amout of bytes
print('started spamming')

for _ in range(10):
    arduino.write(turn_led_on) #Actual byte is 0x58
    print(time.time()-start,'on')
    time.sleep(.5)
    arduino.write(turn_led_off) #Actual byte is 0x18
    print(time.time()-start,'off')
    time.sleep(.5)
```

So I'm switching on and off an LED that is connected to an arduino by sending it the specified bytes: 0x58 and 0x18 The Arduino runs code that looks like this:

```cpp
bool spamming = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(24, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
   while(Serial.available() > 0)
   {
      unsigned char x = Serial.read();
      if (x == 0x58)
      { 
         digitalWrite(24, HIGH); //Turn on LED
      }
      else if (x == 0x18)
      {
         digitalWrite(24, LOW);  //Turn off LED
      }
      else if (x == 0x00)
      {
          spamming = true;
      }
   }
   if (spamming)
   {
      if (Serial.avialiableForWrite() > 0) Serial.write(0x01);
   }
}
```

I get the expected result (which is just the console printing on and off 10 times (on the raspberry side) and the Arduino actually turning the LED on and off 10 times in a row.

I then send a command that will make the Arduino start sending an infinite amount of bytes to the Raspberry Pi whilst still checking the Serial incoming buffer for new commands. After that I repeat the same process as before and try to send the LED switching command.

Now the python console output stays the same (runs without any error raising), yet the program blocks at each arduino.write() command for a long time (around 10s or longer) even though there is a timeout specified (0.1s). After blocking, the console prints as usual and the LED on the arduino switches as usual. I just added timesamps to the python console output and the results look like this:

```
2.002582311630249 on
2.502887725830078 off
3.003848075866699 on
3.5050783157348633 off
4.005117177963257 on
4.5058839321136475 off
5.006282806396484 on
5.50661826133728 off
6.008156776428223 on
6.509922504425049 off
7.010948181152344 on
7.512096166610718 off
8.012341737747192 on
8.513236999511719 off
9.013462543487549 on
9.514604091644287 off
10.015231370925903 on
10.515642404556274 off
11.01583743095398 on
11.516374349594116 off
started spamming
12.018024444580078 on
12.518478155136108 off
13.01881217956543 on
13.519550085067749 off
28.621582508087158 on
44.68230104446411 off
57.40802550315857 on
63.064852714538574 off
65.58953928947449 on
68.61984610557556 off
77.50833535194397 on
96.19384908676147 off
102.6581130027771 on
109.2223105430603 off
132.55511474609375 on
155.684588432312 off
171.44103860855103 on
185.78372859954834 off
199.51972341537476 on
216.58949422836304 off
```

So the problem must be on the raspberry pi. I tried the same code on my windows machine (plugging the arduino in there of course) and the same thing happened, which led to the conclusion that it must have something to do with the virtual COM/Serial port.

So now to the actual question: Why does it take so long for the serial.write() function to write something to the output buffer (on the pi) when the input buffer (on the pi) is beeing spammed by the arduino?
As far as I know, a UART Chip has two physically seperate buffers that are completely independent. Does a virtual COM port not have this independence of the two buffers? (Maybe just some allocated memory for both of them in a stack-heap kind of way?) Or is the problem that USB 1.0 and 2.0 are only half-duplex?
(And then lastly is there a way to fix the fucntion block?)

[update]
I managed to stop the function from blocking by adding

```py
if arduino.inWaiting() >  1000: arduino.flushInput()
```

before every `arduino.write()` statement. I'm still interested in how the Serial/COM port is managed by the operating system, be it linux/raspbian or windows.

Comment: I'm sorry to have confused you. I changed some parts of the question in the hopes that it might clarify the situation. Please feel free to ask for more details in the comments.

Comment: *"... there is a timeout specified (0.1s)"* -- Your description does not match the posted code: `time.sleep(.5)`.  Can you show the Python console output with timestamps?  Instead of simply describing what you actually *observe*, you tell us what you *guess* the program is doing.  *"... the same thing happened, which led to the conclusion that it must have something to do with the virtual COM/Serial port"* -- Faulty conclusion.  Your Python & Arduino programs are also common to both tests.  USB 2.1 has more than sufficient bandwidth to handle a "full duplex" 115200 baud serial link.

Comment: the timeout actually refers to the creation of the serial.Serial object in line 4. Thanks for the idea with the timestamps, I just added them to the code and posted the console log

Comment: *"the timeout actually refers to the creation of the serial.Serial object in line 4"* -- That timeout specification in the open statement is only for reading.  It's `write_timeout=...` that sets a write timeout value.  This issue seems peculiar to Python (and its interpreter).  I've never seen output blocked by accumulation of unread input on any type of port.  Try replacing that Python program with a version in C.  Try adapting this program: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152937/canonical-mode-linux-serial-port/57155531#57155531

Comment: *"how the Serial/COM port is managed by the operating system"* -- That's an ambiguous/broad request, but the low-level concepts for serial terminals in Linux are described in    [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html).  Note that in the last diagram there is no interaction or control logic between outgoing data and incoming data, nor mention of such internal flow control.