# Serial Port Communication using cpp in linux (RS232) with a Mass Flow controller

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I am trying to etablish a comunication with a mass flow controler  using linux and cpp , i write the code but i am not getting any response from my MFC.
I try many think but isnt working.Did I miss somethink or i need  to make some modfication ?

The MFC that i am using is an Alicat MFC, communicate via Serial Port using RS232 protocol and ASCII data.

Thats My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Linux headers
#include <fcntl.h> // Contains file controls like O_RDWR
#include <errno.h> // Error integer and strerror() function
#include <termios.h> // Contains POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <unistd.h> // write(), read(), close()
#include <iostream>

struct termios tty;

using namespace std ;
int main(){

    cout << "step_1\n";
    int serial_port = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY);

    // Check for errors
    if (serial_port < 0)
    {
        printf("Error %i from open: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(-2);
    }
    if(tcgetattr(serial_port, &tty) != 0)
    {
        cout << ("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(-3);
    }
    cout << "step_2\n";
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    tty.c_cflag &=  ~CSTOP;
    tty.c_cflag &=  ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |=     CS8;
    tty.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;
    tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; // Disable echo
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHOE; // Disable erasure
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHONL; // Disable new-line echo
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // Turn off s/w flow ctrl./
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL);
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    tty.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR;


    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 5;

    cfsetispeed(&tty, B19200);
    cfsetospeed(&tty, B19200);

    tcflush( serial_port, TCIFLUSH );
    cout << "step_3\n";

    if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
   cout << "step_4\n";
    tcflush( serial_port , TCIFLUSH );

    cout<< "step_5\n";

    unsigned char cmd[] = "A\r";
    int n_written = 0,
        spot = 0;

    do {
        n_written = write(serial_port, &cmd[spot], sizeof(cmd) - 1 );
        spot += n_written;
    } while (cmd[spot-1] != '\r' && n_written > 0);



    int n = 0;
     spot = 0;
    char buf = '\0';

    /* Whole response*/
    char response[1024];
    memset(response, '\0', sizeof response);

    do {
        n = read( serial_port, &buf, sizeof(buf));
        sprintf( &response[spot], "%c", buf );
        spot += n;
    } while( buf != '\r' && n > 0);

    if (n < 0) {
        std::cout << "Error reading: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }
    else if (n == 0) {
        std::cout << "Read nothing!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Response: " << response << std::endl;
    }

    return -1 ; 
}
```

Comment: I’d start with Python’s serial port support, since it would get rid of all the dark corners of C. Once it works from Python, you can port it to C. It’ll be easier that way.

Comment: If *"ASCII data"* and *"whole response"* means that your program expects to be reading *lines* of text, then your termios configuration (for noncanonical mode) is inappropriate.  Instead of raw mode, you need to use canonical mode.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152937/canonical-mode-linux-serial-port

Comment: Why not look up the information on these support pages? [Support Software & drivers](https://www.alicat.com/support/software-drivers/#g_tab-0-1), [Customization options for Alicat instruments Communication Protocols](https://www.alicat.com/customize/communications-protocols/) Can you use the provided tools?

Comment: No because thia is a part of a cpp Interface that make some automation