# beaglebone black debian uart example c programing

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, embedded-linux, termios

I am running Embedded Linux. but right now I'm new. I want your help on something.

Debian distribution is installed in Beaglebone.

I want to make a uart communication. I am using the beagbone board P9-24 and P9-26 pins via uart1, but when I run the code it does not work.

I installed a ready-made TTL converter to the pins I gave above and I monitor the serial port through the hterm program. I set the baud rate to 9600. When I check my own TTL converter, it works, but when I connect it to the pins and run the program I wrote, I cannot see any output.

Would you help me with this topic?

The code I used is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int open_uart(const char *port) {
    int uart_fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (uart_fd == -1) {
        perror("Error opening UART");
        return -1;
    }

    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr(uart_fd, &options);
    options.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;   // Parity disable
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;   // 1 stop bit
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;       // 8 data bits
    options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = 0;
    tcflush(uart_fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(uart_fd, TCSANOW, &options);

    return uart_fd;
}

void send_data(int uart_fd, const char *data) {
    write(uart_fd, data, strlen(data));
}

int main() {
    const char *uart_port = "/dev/ttyS0"; // Bu portun doğru olup olmadığını kontrol et
    int uart_fd = open_uart(uart_port);

    if (uart_fd != -1) {
        printf("açıldı");
        const char *data_to_send = "Muhammed";
        send_data(uart_fd, data_to_send);
        close(uart_fd); // İşiniz bittiğinde portu kapatmayı unutmayın
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it does not work" What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Do you get garbage? What kind of device are you writing to? Please update your answer to provide more info.

Comment: When I compile and run the code I gave above for beaglebone, I do not receive any error output. But the code does not work because I do not get any output from the pins.

Comment: is your user allowed to access this port?

Comment: Yes the user has access to this port.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", then come back and [edit] your question, providing the information you're asked for. Do not add information in comments this is not a forum. -- How do you observe the output at the pins?

Comment: I control the pin outputs with a ttl converter. I set the Hterm program to 8n1 at 9600 speed. I checked the ttl conversion by sharing tx-rx, rx-tx and gnd pins on p9-22 and p9-24 pins, but I could not see any data output.

Comment: The Linux kernel does not allow user apps to directly access hardware (e.g. a UART), so your program is reading/writing a *serial terminal*. See [Linux serial drivers](https://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html). Your use of the termios API is broken; see [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html) For working code, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152937/canonical-mode-linux-serial-port/57155531#57155531

Comment: "*I checked the ttl conversion by sharing tx-rx, rx-tx and gnd pins on p9-22 and p9-24 pins*" - What that is supposed to mean is not clear at all. Apparently the hardware confuses you, and you don't know which pins belong to **/dev/ttyS0**. BTW `p9-22` is normally assigned to UART2_RXD, and `p9-24` to UART1_TXD. This seems to be a hardware connection problem. Until that's corrected, no code fix-up will help. Vote to close

Comment: Perhaps it would be more appropriate to ask your question on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beaglebone) instead of StackOverflow.