Problem in reading NMEA data using Raspberry Pi 4b
I'm trying to read the NMEA Sentences from GPS Module using RPi 4b.
I'm using the following python code for the reading the data:
import serial
from time import sleep

uart = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/serial0",baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1.0, bytesize = 8, stopbits = 1)

while True:
    data = uart.read(1000)
    print(data.decode('utf-8', errors = 'ignore'))
    print('\n')

I'm getting a very inconsistent output.
Could anyone please tell what is the problem with the python code and what are the possible ways to solve them?

Your question is a bit generic. Could you explain the very inconsistent output? And maybe can you copy some output, and your expectation?

"Getting a very inconsistent output" is an ambiguous (and therefore low-quality) description of results. However since the source is specified and your code is simple, a guess is possible. The device /dev/serial0 is actually a symbolic link to a /dev/ttySn device, which is for a serial terminal rather than just a UART. See Linux serial drivers. You need to be aware that the serial terminal can be raw mode or canonical mode (to read lines of text).

Your code uses a serial terminal mode to read the incoming data as raw data, but then assumes that whatever is in the buffer is a line of text, and appends a newline character. That's inconsistent treatment/handling of the received data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757505/how-to-read-from-serial-port-like-picocom-on-linux/56765890#56765890

It might be worth removing the errors = 'ignore' parameter so that you can see more clearly what is going wrong. Then post you inconsistent output so we can see what is happening.
