# Within C program use Picocom to read/write streams

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, debian

I am thinking of creating a C program that will use picocom to read and write serial streams to ports (GPS module, NTPD). The c program will run on a Debian OS.

Is it possible to do this using Picocom? Is it bad design to interact with Picocom through c and system commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While that's technically possible, it's a bad idea; picocom is a somewhat uncommon tool, and it's primarily designed to be used interactively by a user. Trying to use it from within another application will be pretty weird.

It'll be much easier to interact with the serial port directly from your application. There's a nice introduction to doing that in the answer to [How to open, read, and write from serial port in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6947758).