# Serial Port communication using C

Tags: c, serial-port

I am developing a software wherein I have to receive data via serial port. I am opening the port in canonical mode and setting the VEOL flag to **0X78**(hexadecimal). The problem I am facing is that read is exiting every time it receives byte value **0X0A** in between. Can somebody help me in resolving this issue, I want read to block till I receive end byte as **0X78**. This is the code I have written so far

```
struct termios tio;
char buf[255];

int fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY); 
if (fd <0) {
    perror(MODEMDEVICE);
    exit(−1); 
}

bzero(&tio, sizeof(tio));
tio.c_cflag = B115200 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
tio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
tio.c_oflag = 0;
tio.c_lflag = 1;
tio.c_cc[VEOL] = 0X78;

tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&tio);


int read=read(fd,buf,255);

printf("Number of bytes read is %d\n",read);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try not sending newlines on the other side?

Comment: It's probably not intended to be newlines but part of a binary data stream, otherwise the OP could have just used newlines as terminators in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually 0x0A is part of the data that I'm receiving. So I want to know if its possible to block read till last byte comes as 0X78

Comment: Looks to me like you can not use canonical mode for binary data http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcsetattr.3.html

Comment: You can't use the built-in "read until newline" mechanism then - instead, read one character at a time and append it to your buffer, and stop when you encounter your termination character.

Comment: Take a look at the sample in [how to open, read, and write from serial port in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c/6947758#6947758) which has canonical turned off. You still will need to process the byte stream to determine the end of a set. You might do this by reading one byte at a time or by implementing your own buffering. Or perhaps the device will only send the necessary number of characters so you just need to read until no more bytes come in?

Comment: Certainly, some drivers have the ability to have a single trigger character set.  If this is not exposed to the OS, or the OS does nto expose it to the user processes, then.. ;(    Alternatively, write your app on Windows, where the DCB does expose an 'EvtChar': https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: *"tio.c_lflag = 1"* -- That's really bad coding.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237).  As @RichardChambers already suggested, you shouldn't be using canonical mode for reading binary data (but he pointed you to a poor example).  The EOL characters must be unique in your character set for text.  If you use noncanonical mode, then you could ***escape*** the intermediate 0x78s, but that means that the sender has to do the escaping, and you need to write a parser at the receive end.

Answer (score 0):

[The manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcsetattr.3.html) states:

> VEOL   (0, NUL) Additional end-of-line character (EOL).  Recognized
>                 when ICANON is set.

So, it doesn't *replace* all end-of-line characters, it just adds one more, meaning 0xa is still active.

Don't send the wrong data, or filter them out in software.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually 0x0A is part of the data that I'm receiving. So I want to know if its possible to block read till last byte comes as 0X78