# redirect UART data to pcie port

Tags: c, linux, uart, pci-e

I wanted to transmit the data coming to PCIE over to UART.And I have linux os.

Is there anyway that I can redirect the UART data over PCIE slot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's depend of your PCIe device. What is your PCIe device ?

Comment: @FabienM :- I have one microtik rf device. Its connected via PCI to my board. My board is running on linux( openWRT).

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Linux driver for your PCIe device. If you don't have a Linux driver for it you can access to your PCIe memory space via mmap() in userland like with [pci_debug](http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Pci_debug).

Once you have PCIe access you will have to write a Linux application that read/write the serial port tty (/dev/ttyXX) and read/write on your PCIe device.

There is lot's of way to write a Linux application.

[edit]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c#6947758) you can see how read write on Linux serial port in C. Reading the C source code of pci_debug available [here](http://www.ovro.caltech.edu/%7Edwh/correlator/pdf/altera_pcie.zip), you can see how to read/write on PCIe BAR memory with mmap.

Comment: :-Thanks for Replay.
 I got pci device driver. That I have installed also. 
And Can you point me to any example application to start with.

Comment: What is the name of your pci device driver ?

Comment: hi @FabienM :- I got linux running on board. and over PCI I have wireless transmitter. So It's generic and IP address also I can set on my own.

Comment: If you want to use mmap() like with pci_debug program, you must not mount your pci wireless driver.

Comment: @FebienM : ok I got it. There is another ethernet port is there with IpV4 address assigned. If I can redirect that also, work is done for me. is it possible?