# reading from serial port always returns what was written

Tags: c, serial-port, usb

I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero in device mode and a Raspberry Pi B in host mode. I'm connecting the two with a USB cable. My goal right now is just to send simple, arbitrary data back and forth between the two Pi's.

The problem is whichever Pi writes to the serial port first ends up reading what it wrote. The program I've written has the device send `d\n` and the host send `h\n`. So, if the device writes first, the the host reads correctly the `d\n`, then writes `h\n` to the serial port. But the device ends up reading `d\n`! The problem persists if I switch it so that the host writes first.

I've tried adding various `tcflush` calls to the program after writing but before reading, but it doesn't work. I've also tried sleeping for various amounts of time. I've read waiting 100 microseconds for each character written and I've slept for several seconds.

My setup requires me to not have a constant connection between both Pi's at the same time because of the Pi Zero's single data-capable usb port. So, to test, I'm actually plugging in a keyboard and running the program, then plugging in the proper cable to transfer data. I can transfer data, but not after writing because the program simply reads back what it wrote.

I'm starting to think I've fallen into a noob trap that I can't fathom. Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>

/*
 * gcc -o device_rw -DDEVICE serial_rw.c
 * gcc -o host_rw serial_rw.c
 */

#define SERIAL_DEVICE "/dev/ttyGS0"
#define SERIAL_HOST   "/dev/ttyACM0"

#ifdef DEVICE
#define _TTY SERIAL_DEVICE
#else
#define _TTY SERIAL_HOST
#endif

int
set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed)
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     /* only need 1 stop bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */

    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no hardware flowcontrol */
    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);    /* ignore modem controls */

    tty.c_iflag |= IGNPAR | IGNCR;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    tty.c_iflag |= ICANON;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~OPOST;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void
write_serial (int fd, const char *buf, int len)
{
    printf("WRITE: %s\n", buf);
    write(fd, buf, len);
}

void
read_serial (int fd, char *buf, int len)
{
    ssize_t nread = read(fd, buf, len);
    if (nread > 0 && nread <= len) {
      buf[nread] = 0;
      printf(" READ: %s\n", buf);
    }
}

int 
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[80];
    int fd = open(_TTY, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    if (fd < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s: %s\n", _TTY, strerror(errno));
      goto exit;
    }

    if (set_interface_attribs(fd, B115200) < 0) {
      goto exit;
    }

#ifdef DEVICE
    printf("device: %s\n", _TTY);
    write_serial(fd, "d\n", 2);
    usleep((2 + 25) * 100);
    read_serial(fd, buf, 2);
#else
    printf("host: %s\n", _TTY);
    read_serial(fd, buf, 2);
    //usleep((2 + 25) * 100);
    write_serial(fd, "h\n", 2);
#endif

    close(fd);
exit:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where have you put `#define DEVICE` to satisfy your compilation versions controlled by `#ifdef DEVICE`?

Comment: I compile with `-DDEVICE` to trigger it.

Comment: Oh I see, as commented in the code. But I don't like it - can lead to finger trouble. I suggest a *specific value* must be defined so the compilation will fail without it.

Comment: Try adding `tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that didn't do the trick. Still reading data written.

Comment: It could be that you physical connection is shorting RX to TX. Try disconnection it and re-run.

Comment: the function: `strerror()` requires the header file: `string.h`

Comment: when writing the `main()` function signature and the parameters are not going to be used, use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: the third parameter of the function: `write()` is expected to be a `size_t` not an `int`

Comment: this line: `if (nread > 0 && nread <= len) {` is not a good idea.  Suggest: `if (nread > 0) {`.

Comment: the problem seems to be in the function: `set_interface_attribs()`  I suspect the interface is initialized to 'echo on'  and the initialization code in the function does not turn that echo mode OFF.   A test of extending the length of the `read() might make that obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned a lot from everyone's answers and am grateful for them because I will need them as I move on with this project. For *this* particular case, however, the issue ended up being permissions. Yep, file permissions on `ttyGSO`.

I completely expected a `permission denied` error from `open` and never got one, so I never considered the possibility. Especially since I opened the files in `RDWR` mode, I could write to the serial file, and it *appeared* I was reading data (although the same data) it never dawned on me that perhaps I didn't have read permissions.

Answer (score 4):

Beside not disabling the ECHO attributes (as @MarkPlotnick commented), you have two misapplied assignments:

```
tty.c_iflag |= ICANON;
```

ICANON belongs to the lflag member, and

```
tty.c_iflag &= ~OPOST;
```

OPOST belongs to the oflag member.
Considering these errors, did you properly apply @MarkPlotnick's suggestion?

See [Working with linux serial port in C, Not able to get full data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224496/working-with-linux-serial-port-in-c-not-able-to-get-full-data/41252962#41252962) for a working canonical setup.

```
cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

tty.c_cflag |= CLOCAL | CREAD;
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */
tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     /* only need 1 stop bit */
tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no hardware flowcontrol */

tty.c_lflag |= ICANON | ISIG;  /* canonical input */
tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHOE | ECHONL | IEXTEN);

tty.c_iflag &= ~INPCK;
tty.c_iflag |= IGNCR;
tty.c_iflag &= ~(INLCR | ICRNL | IUCLC | IMAXBEL);
tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);   /* no SW flowcontrol */

tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
```

---

Note that it is also possible to have echo enabled on the far end.
To determine if the echo is generated locally or from the far end, simply disconnect the remote device (assuming you're using UARTs and/or USB-to-serial adapters), and transmit.
If you still get echo, then it's generated locally, which is controlled by the *termios* ECHO attributes.
If you no longer get an echo, then it's the remote unit that is repeating its input back to the sender.

---

BTW Your program as posted does not compile cleanly.
It's missing `#include <string.h>`
The *termios* initialization routine that you copied (but then incorrectly modified) has proper checking of return values, but your read and write routines do not check for errors.