# How to do an asynchronius RS485/Serial communication in Linux (in ANSI C)?

Tags: c, linux, io, serial-port, rs485

Hej,

I am running a custom build Linux for an embedded device. This device has a RS485 which is mapped to /dev/ttyS2. Actually I am looking for an example how to set up an asynchronous communication (async read/write calls).
My actual solution works like that:

- open ttyS2
- setup ttyS2 like [in this example "how to open, read, and write from serial port in C"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c)
- configure ttyS2 RS485 like [in this example "kernel.org RS485 SERIAL COMMUNICATIONS"](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt)
- set some pins of my custom mainboard
- create pthread and call read on ttyS2
- wait in my main function for inputs and send them via write to ttyS2

I discovered that every time when I am writing to ttyS2 and reading from it artefacts where generated. An example:

```
int fd;
fd = open("/dev/ttyS2", O_RDWR);
@my RX thread:
for (;;) {
amount = read(fd, rxBuffer, 1024);
printf("[rx]:%i\n", amount);
}
@my main:
char * myText = "hello";
printf("[tx]: %s\n",myText);
amount = write(fd, myText,strlen(myText));
```

The output looks like:

```
[tx]: hello
[rx]: 1
[rx]: 1
[rx]: 1
[rx]: 1
[rx]: 1
```

This means that the ttyS2 switches the RS485 between rx/tx and generates the artificial bytes. When using an RS232 it's not failing(because RS232 is duplex).

I like to keep my asynchronous program design. But I need to interrupt the RX operations before initiating the TX ones. So far I did not discovered an "chancel(fd, RX)" command for making read to stop.

How would you solve this problem? Ideas and examples are welcome

Comment: What bytes does it read? Is it that "hello" text back, or what?

Comment: Anyway, using threads may have its own complications (safely communicating between threads). You might want to consider more traditionall `poll`/`select` loop (here's a decent guide for using `select`, it's more about network sockets but applies to any socket: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Comment: RS422 is half-duplex, while RS485 supports full-duplex.