# RFID data packet

Tags: c++, linux, rfid

I'm working on access control system. One of the access method is the conventional RFID. 
I'm using a UHF reader to read RFIDs. I read a bunch of hex from the reader. I did a small research on the internet for RFID data packet standards. Couldn't fix on one.

I'm using ZKTeco UHF Reader. Can I get a standard RFID data packet for the same?

EDIT

======
\
I'm using this code for serial communication : [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38318768/7018980)

This is what I see when I run the above code:

`Read 4:`

`0xf0 0x2 
 0xa 
 0x4`

`Read 4:  0xf4`
 `0x3 
 0xee 
 0x2`

Read 1:  0x19

Read 4:  0xf0 
 0x10 
 0xee 
 0x1

Read 4:  0x6 
 0x5a 
 0x4b
 0x43

Read 4:  0xe9 
 0x55 
 0x55 
 0x55

Read 4:  0x55 
 0x5a
 0x4b 
 0x43

Read 2:  0xe9 
 0x15`

Comment: `minicom` gave me the same data stream but in characters

Answer (score 2):

Your reader apparently operates on the [ISO/IEC 18000](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:18000:-63:ed-2:v1:en) standard type C part 63 ( UHF from 860-960mhz ).

The hex response depends on the interrogation command sent.
If the hex response is consistent for the same RFID tag, then that alone can pretty much be all you need for pre-shared identification (not very secure if you ask me).

Please provide more details on RFID tags used, interrogation and hex response.

Comment: Pls see the edited question. That's the response I get when I wave the tag in front of the UHF reader.