# uart communication in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, uart

I have a UART-based device, [ESP8266EX](http://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf), and I need to write to its driver for Linux. Since I am new to writing kernel drivers is there any example or method for accessing uart reading and writing through kernel driver. How is it different from user space uart code?
I have a small iot board with mu device connected to /dev/ttymxc1 port so the uart port will remain fixed for this device and also the device will work at fixed 115200 baud rate. I should be able to read and write to uart from kernel.

Comment: *UART based device* is slave of master? From context it sounds like a slave. Thus, what is that device? Since for most devices you don't need to have a kernel driver (there is a user space available API for that, called TERMIOS).

Comment: The device is wifi module(AT command based)

Comment: Any datasheet or link to it?

Comment: https://espressif.com/en/products/hardware/esp8266ex/overview it's ep8266 module

Comment: I see. You perhaps just can use SDIO variant https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39344/installing-esp8266-sdio-driver-make-command-gives-kernel-build-tree-not-foun

Comment: Due to some reason I can't use sdio variant currently in my board and thus I thought of writing drivers for uart. Can we use user space Uart code to read and write to Uart from kernel?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in user space.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you provide some tutorial or link how to read and write to UART code?

Comment: There's also serdev which is a new serial device bus being phased into kernel v4.11. The advantage is that it provides nice abstractions, so e.g. even if the UART device is connected via USB-serial converter (e.g. ttyUSB0) or whatever happens to be underlying communication mechanism, that will be abstracted away from driver code.

Comment: *"Can you provide some tutorial or link how to read and write to UART code?"* -- UARTs in Linux are typically implemented as serial terminals, and the API is termios.  See [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).  For sample code see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c/38318768#38318768