# Forcing raw serial mode in C - linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, stty

Not sure how to word the title, but what I'm trying to do is test my micro controller with my Linux PC to ensure data is correct. After hours of searching, I found out that the stty command can change how data is managed through the serial port and it turned out that by default if xon or xoff characters are received from the port, they don't get displayed. At first I thought my computer was too slow that I was losing characters at 57.6Kbps but that wasn't the case.

Back in the day when I was playing with the serial mouse in QuickBasic for DOS, I could use this command to start the serial port:

```
OPEN "com1:1200,n,7,1,op0" for binary as #1
```

So what I want to do now is create something simple in C that would allow me to open up the serial port in the rawest mode possible. I want it so that whatever data I give to it is sent to it unmodified. I also want to receive data unmodified. so if the controller decides to send a character the PC would recognize as a special control code, I still want to see the character, not have the PC go funny just because a character matches a control code.

One idea I thought of is to create a fork to the stty program and use nearly every (50+?) parameters added to the program making the requirement of program stack space a bit high.

Another idea I thought of is to do direct I/O with the port address itself (using inb and outb) but I'm not sure if the kernel would run those commands through anything else before the data reaches the port, but I'd rather use that as a last option in case I ever replace my computer and the serial port value changes (or becomes a serial port made through USB to serial converter hardware).

so rather than inb and outb and those variants (like inw), and without executing stty with specifying 50+ parameters in my program, is there a function in C I can use (without requiring a special library not included with a standard linux distribution) to force the serial port device as a raw device so I can do any I/O on it without the kernel modifying or dropping data?

Comment: man [`termios`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) is the usual starting point

Comment: i'm currently looking in that manual right now

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c

Comment: *"force the serial port device as a raw device"* -- That's called non-canonical (aka raw) mode.  See  [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)