# Linux UART transmitting Problems

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, uart, tty

I'm trying to communicate with an external IC via UART/tty in C. I'm using a nanoPI neo2 (allwinner h5) and friendlyARM's own Linux OS (which is a modified Ubuntu core).

I'v tried to get it working, but the TX output of the pi is ?logical inverted?. You can see what I mean in the oscilloscope pictures. There you can see if I select the "Polarity Invert"- Mode the data is ok, but in normal mode it isn't working.

In the past, I got around that by setting the invert Bit of the MCU (e.g. PIC MCU), but the IC I'm using now doesn't support this feature.

http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_NEO2

[oscilloscope picture 1](https://hieber.xyz/DSX_QuickPrint3_1.jpg)

[oscilloscope picture 2](https://hieber.xyz/DSX_QuickPrint2_1.jpg)

[c source](https://gist.github.com/jerome-labidurie/5dde0ec105fe88aaf5fa8f3c54f4b07d)

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <errno.h>
//#include <termios.h>
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


#include <fcntl.h>  /* File Control Definitions          */
#include <termios.h>/* POSIX Terminal Control Definitions*/
#include <unistd.h> /* UNIX Standard Definitions         */
#include <errno.h>  /* ERROR Number Definitions          */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
/* source : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6947758 */

int fd;

int set_interface_attribs (int fd, int speed, int parity) {
        struct termios tty;
        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
        if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0) {
                perror ("error from tcgetattr");
                return -1;
        }

        cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
        cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

        tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
        // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
        // as \000 chars
        tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
        tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                        // no canonical processing
        tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
        tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
        tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

        tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

        tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                                        // enable reading
        tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
        tty.c_cflag |= parity;
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

        if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
                perror ("error from tcsetattr");
                return -1;
        }
        return 0;
}

void set_blocking (int fd, int should_block) {
        struct termios tty;
        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
        if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
        {
                perror ("error from tggetattr");
                return;
        }

        tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = should_block ? 1 : 0;
        tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

        if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
                perror ("error setting term attributes");
}

int main()
{
    char *portname = "/dev/ttyS0";
    int fd = open (portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
            //perror ("error %d opening %s: %s", errno, portname, strerror (errno));
            return;
    }
    set_interface_attribs (fd, B115200, 0);  // set speed to 115,200 bps, 8n1 (no parity)
    set_blocking (fd, 0);                // set no blocking
    write (fd, "hello!\n", 7);           // send 7 character greeting
    usleep ((7 + 25) * 100);             // sleep enough to transmit the 7 plus
                                         // receive 25:  approx 100 uS per char transmit
    char buf [100];
    int n = read (fd, buf, sizeof buf);  // read up to 100 characters if ready to read

}
```

Thanks in advance

Axel

Answer (score 1):

The picture on the scope looks fine - it is an UART signal. The problem here is not programming-related, but failure to understand the difference between UART and RS-232.

You have picked RS-232 encoding on your scope, and RS-232 uses a different, inverted polarity compared to UART.

- UART idles high voltage=Vdd, RS-232 idles at negative voltage < -3V.
- On UART, a high voltage=Vdd bit means 1 and low voltage=0V means 0.
- On RS-232, a high voltage > +3V bit means 0, and negative voltage < -3V means 1.

So when you try to decode a UART signal with RS-232 encoding, it works when you inverse the polarity. Apparently Rigol isn't picky about the actual voltage levels, since it doesn't understand that the signal is not RS-232 at all.

Comment: IIRC, if you use a V24 driver chip, it inverts the logic.

Comment: @MartinJames Any RS-232 transceiver (MAX232 & friends) will invert the UART logic to RS-232 logic.