# Send Commands to serial device and receiving response

Tags: c, linux, arduino, raspberry-pi

Am trying to send a command to a serial device (arduino) and receive a response, the command goes through but I don't get a response from the target device.

I want the `C` program to control the serial device by sending & receiving data.

`Arduino` Code:

```
void setup() {
    // initialize serial communication:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        int inByte = Serial.read();
        switch (inByte) {
          case 'H':
              Serial.print("75864d63001bebaa");
              break;
        }
    }
}
```

`C` Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd, n, i;
    char buf[64] = "temp text";
    struct termios toptions;

    /* open serial port */
    fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    printf("fd opened as %i\n", fd);

    /* wait for the Arduino to reboot */
    usleep(3500000);

    /* get current serial port settings */
    tcgetattr(fd, &toptions);
    /* set 9600 baud both ways */
    cfsetispeed(&toptions, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&toptions, B9600);
    /* 8 bits, no parity, no stop bits */
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    toptions.c_cflag |= CS8;
    /* Canonical mode */
    toptions.c_lflag |= ICANON;
    /* commit the serial port settings */
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &toptions);

    /* Send byte to trigger Arduino to send string back */
    write(fd, "H", 1);

    /* Receive string from Arduino */
    n = read(fd, buf, 64);
    /* insert terminating zero in the string */
    buf[n] = 0;

    printf("%i bytes read, buffer contains: %s\n", n, buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where your comment says: 'wait for arduino to reboot", you are not actually waiting, perhaps the arduino is still starting up by the time you write and therefore nothing to be read? The instructions following the opening of the port are quite quickly accomplished on most machines

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it when I copy past the code but I have usleep(3500000); under reboot and still not working

Comment: usleep might cause a system issue if arg >=1,000,000 and could possibly be a no-op, perhaps use sleep with smaller value? only about 2s

Comment: what is the return value from open? Perhaps your current linux user is not apart of the dialout group?

Comment: fd opened as 3, running under pi user

Comment: I usually use this code as a starting point when playing with serial ports: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c

Comment: Someone should post an answer to this problem. @Djmc, you are responsible for that when you find a solution, if nobody else posts it.

Comment: If I find a solution I'll post it no problem.