# open function doesn't return for serial port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I have a USB serial port module and I want to use it in my C application. The problem is the **open** system call doesn't return!

> int serialDevice = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY); // doesn't return

I added my user to dialout group and I can access the port without root access using minicom in terminal. So it's not permission problem. Even if it is, it should return instantly and give permission error. But open function doesn't return at all.

What should I do? Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can happen if the device is busy, etc..

You need to add the flag **O_NONBLOCK**:

> O_NONBLOCK
>       When opening a FIFO with O_RDONLY or O_WRONLY set: 
>   *
>       If O_NONBLOCK is set, an open() for reading-only shall return without delay. An open() for writing-only shall return an error if no
>   process currently has the file open for reading. 
>   *
>       If O_NONBLOCK is clear, an open() for reading-only shall block the calling thread until a thread opens the file for writing. An open()
>   for writing-only shall block the calling thread until a thread opens
>   the file for reading.
>
> When opening a block special or character special file that supports
>   non-blocking opens:
>
> ```
> *
>     If O_NONBLOCK is set, the open() function shall return without blocking for the device to be ready or available. Subsequent behavior
> ```
>
> of the device is device-specific. 
>       *
>           If O_NONBLOCK is clear, the open() function shall block the calling thread until the device is ready or available before
>   returning.
>
> Otherwise, the behavior of O_NONBLOCK is unspecified.

Comment: The device was not busy because I was able to open ttyUSB0 using minicom but  O_NONBLOCK solved the problem. I don't care why this happened. It works. Thanks.

Comment: Now read function always return successful even though the serial cable is disconnected. Is it because of this blocking flag?

Comment: It was because of wrong serial settings. It's ok now.

Answer (score 2):

> int serialDevice = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

In addition to @darune's answer and `O_NONBLOCK`, you might consider `O_SYNC` too. Also see [How to open, read, and write from serial port in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6947413/608639)

You might also consider making the file descriptor exclusive so another program like Modem Manager does not open the device and [muck with your state](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=683839). Exclusive is fine because of `O_RDWR`. Also see [How to make /dev/ttyACM0 (and friends) exclusive?](https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2019-March/019828.html) on the Kernel Newbies mailing list.

To make the file descriptor exclusive you need to use `ioctl` and `TIOCEXCL`. `O_EXCL` does not work as expected because it is not honored for character devices (and the kernel folks say `-ENOPATCH`).

```
int term_config(int fd, int speed)
{
    struct termios tty;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0) {
        log_error("term_config: tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfmakeraw(&tty);
    tty.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;   /* ignore status lines   */
    tty.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;  /* hardware flow control */

    cfsetospeed(&tty,(speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty,(speed_t)speed);

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        log_error("term_config: tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if (ioctl(fd, TIOCEXCL, NULL) != 0) {
        log_error("term_config: ioctl_tty: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You would call `term_config` something like:

```
int serialDevice = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", ...);
if (serialDevice == -1) { /* error */ }

int result = term_config(serialDevice, B115200);
if (result != 0) { /* error */ }
```