# Serial communication over RS-232 stops after a while, can't transfer data, why?

Tags: c, linux, usb, serial-communication, termios

I am trying to communicate between a special board(details below) and my notebook with RS-232 protocol over USB to TTL [converters](https://www.hotmcu.com/ft232rl-usb-to-ttl-serial-module-p-116.html) ([datasheet](http://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/FT232RL/FT232R_v104.pdf)). I use [GtkTerm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gtkterm)(version 1.0) on my notebook. On board I use [minicom](https://linux.die.net/man/1/minicom)(version 2.7).

I can send data at the beginning with no error also on GtkTerm I can send raw files which can be monitored over minicom on board. After a while I can not transfer data or get any response from minicom of board. I tried to communicate over minicom on both devices the problem is still there.

I am working with an embedded board which is special product. It has Texas Instruments [AM4376BZDN80](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/AM4376BZDN80/296-42748-ND/5226684) ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am4376.pdf)) microprocessor on it. Ubuntu is running on this board. Details for `uname -a`: `Linux *companyname* 4.14.40-51464-gaf2366a-dirty #13 PREEMPT Mon Dec 2 09:43:55 +03 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`.

I am working with a notebook with Ubuntu 19.10 and details for `uname -a`: `Linux Lenovo 5.3.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 01:33:18 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Details of the driver I am using for USB to TTL converter.

Kernel Module: **`modinfo ftdi_sio`**:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    USB FTDI Serial Converters Driver
author:         Greg Kroah-Hartman <greg@kroah.com>, Bill Ryder <bryder@sgi.com>, Kuba Ober <kuba@mareimbrium.org>, Andreas Mohr, Johan Hovold <jhovold@gmail.com>
srcversion:     973CCF3AD54611DBC628693
alias:          usb:v0920p7500d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0403p8348d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v22B7p150Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in01*
alias:          usb:v1C40p0477d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1E8Ep6001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04B4pF900d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04B4p009Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0451pC32Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A5Cp6422d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
...
alias:          usb:v0403pD9A8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1901p0015d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v058Bp0043d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in01*
alias:          usb:v058Bp0028d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in01*
alias:          usb:v0403pCB08d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05D1p8004d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
...
alias:          usb:v0C6Cp04B2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1514p2008d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in02*
alias:          usb:v04D8p000Ad*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFip00in*
alias:          usb:v0456pF001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0456pF000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
...
alias:          usb:v0403p9F80d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0403pFFA8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0403pFF00d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0403pF60Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0403pF608d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0403pF7C0d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0403p0000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        usbserial
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ftdi_sio
vermagic:       5.3.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        37:BE:2D  ...  97:58:77:1C:1B
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      4A:E1:50:53:10:61:08:46:4C:95:07:E7:AE:2A:22:D0:12:A1:42:DD:
        09:77:73:96:6E:4A:BB:26:F4:EA:6B:DB:DB:7E:07:EA:A0:DF:E0:FF:
        B3:96:11:B3:E4:33:9D:29:52:56:37:E1:1A:08:49:AE:EF:E4:30:3D:
...
        78:C9:E9:84:85:23:7D:4C:64:20:8D:48:3F:C1:01:72:E1:36:14:D5:
        77:C5:25:E2:4A:A5:84:1D:75:D3:2D:4B:F7:9E:94:DF:10:0F:13:54:
        17:F1:3C:62:F0:3F:AD:57:26:CC:59:44:B8:71:53:B7:F4:56:32:A2:
        21:C9:B8:F9:5E:63:9D:5F:A8:B6:51:F8:F6:DA:FB:97:6B:94:5D:76:
        AF:50:EA:33:00:23:88:7B:BE:34:4F:E0:D0:C7:C0:0C:0C:34:44:51:
        B8:E4:EC:E0:7B:36:DD:79:88:F8:E9:15
parm:           ndi_latency_timer:NDI device latency timer override (int)
```

---

Right now I am testing serial console with baud rate 115200 8N1 with disabled flow controls. In future I will use higher baud rate nearly 500000 in a C program which transfers data. So I am looking for a solution independent from baud rates.

I wonder is there a special setting for buffer size or time out? I think it may be because of buffer but on minicom there is not a setting related with buffer. How can I learn about buffer limit? I am searching over equivalent settings in `<termios.h>`. I am using code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38318768/9052234). I have tried to communicate over two C programs and still after some time data transfer is not happening.

PS: Let me know if I have mistakes with English in this text. Don't hesitate to ask for more information but I can't provide much more details about board because it is not a public device.

EDIT:

I unplugged both cables and retried the procedure this time I had to transfer a bit more data to obtain same situation. I also removed USB Hub and directly plugged converter to notebook.

dmesg on my notebook

```
[751114.353945] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[751114.353946] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[751114.353947] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[751114.353948] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[751114.353991] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[751114.353992] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[751114.353993] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[751114.353993] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[752203.675249] usb 1-2: clear tt 1 (9231) error -71
[752203.675361] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 35
[752203.675363] usb 1-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 36
[752203.675542] usb 1-2: clear tt 1 (9231) error -71
[752203.675798] ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[752203.675824] ftdi_sio 1-2.4:1.0: device disconnected
[752206.940824] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 37 using xhci_hcd
[752207.089000] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=214b, idProduct=7000, bcdDevice= 1.00
[752207.089002] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[752207.089004] usb 1-2: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[752207.089731] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
[752207.089748] hub 1-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[752238.960329] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 37
[752245.180955] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
[752245.334394] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[752245.334397] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[752245.334400] usb 1-2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[752245.334401] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[752245.334403] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: A50285BI
[752245.337563] ftdi_sio 1-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[752245.337602] usb 1-2: Detected FT232RL
[752245.337920] usb 1-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

dmesg on board(AM437x)

```
[17845.257286] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[17845.270578] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[17845.284742] ftdi_sio 1-1.2:1.0: device disconnected
[17852.021023] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci-hcd
[17852.122251] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[17852.129248] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[17852.137259] usb 1-1.2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[17852.142209] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[17852.146573] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: A50285BI
[17852.162378] ftdi_sio 1-1.2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[17852.177916] usb 1-1.2: Detected FT232RL
[17852.187030] usb 1-1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[17928.632376] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[17929.969381] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[17988.165093] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[18032.176046] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
```

I also recognized the statement below in dmesg.

```
[12191.865894] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: failed to get modem status: -32
```

Comment: Do you observe any suspicious messages from the kernel ring buffer (`dmesg`)? I had the issue that the USB port flaps regularly due to bad cabling/connections.

Comment: I have updated question with dmesg outputs and removed usb hub and directly connected converter to notebook's usb port.

Comment: Could be overrun or underrun due to disabled flow control.

Comment: I think problem is DTR and RTS were enabled on GtkTerm and on minicom both disabled. However still this error is shown in dmesg: 

```ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32```

Comment: @stark , I want to update that I can transfer one way from board to notebook. Vice versa I can't transfer data even I have same settings.