# Why is my Raspberry Pi's serial port not writeable? write() writes zero bytes. select() times out

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, serial-port, tty

**Backstory**: I recently got a [Raspberry Pi 4 Model B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/) and a [Protoneer RPI CNC Hat](https://wiki.protoneer.co.nz/Raspberry_Pi_CNC), which it controls via the serial port (`/dev/ttyAMA0`). After I put it all together and it didn't work at all (either in [Minicom](https://linux.die.net/man/1/minicom) or [bCNC](https://github.com/vlachoudis/bCNC/wiki)), I've been gradually trying to zero in on the source of the problem. My oscilloscope shows that I can control the relevant pins when using them as GPIOs, so I do not suspect a fundamental hardware problem. However, I am completely unable to provoke a response from the pins when using them as a serial port. I have written the below C program to characterize the issue as exactly as possible.

**Problem**: I have a serial port, `/dev/ttyAMA0`, and it doesn't work.

```
$ sudo cat /proc/tty/driver/ttyAMA
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:PL011 rev2 mmio:0xFE201000 irq:34 tx:59596 rx:3105 RTS|CTS|DTR

$ ls -l /dev/ttyAMA0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64 Jul 11 08:24 /dev/ttyAMA0

$ groups
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi

$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000258] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.420424] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 34, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    0.425685] fe215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 36, base_baud = 62500000) is a 16550
[    1.857049] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.

$ echo hello | cat - > /dev/ttyAMA0
cat: write error: No space left on device
```

I can successfully `open()` it, but when I use `select()` to wait for it to become writeable, it times out. When I attempt to write to it anyway, `write()` successfully writes 0 bytes.

```
/* Shamelessly stolen from Stack Overflow, and then modified (in the finest tradition).
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c */

#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed)
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);    /* ignore modem controls */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     /* only need 1 stop bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no hardware flowcontrol */

    /* setup for non-canonical mode */
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    /* fetch bytes as they become available */
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char *portname = "/dev/ttyAMA0";
    int fd;
    int wlen;

    fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open: error");
        return -1;
    }
    /* baudrate 115200, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit */
    set_interface_attribs(fd, B115200);

    /* select() on the serial port file descriptor to wait for it to be writeable.
     * It never does become writeable. Removing this section does not change
     * the behavior of the following call to write() */
    fd_set wfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int select_retval;
    FD_ZERO(&wfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &wfds);
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    select_retval = select(fd + 1, NULL, &wfds, NULL, &tv);
    if (select_retval == -1)
    {
        perror("select: error");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (select_retval)
    {
        printf("select: fd can be written now\n");
    }
    else
    {
        /* This is what happens */
        printf("select: fd did not become writeable within 5 seconds\n");
    }

    /* Write some output. This returns 0 bytes written and no errors. */
    wlen = write(fd, "Hello!\n", 7);
    if (wlen == -1)
    {
        perror("write: error");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("write: wrote %d bytes\n", wlen);

    tcdrain(fd);
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -std=gnu17 -o serial-test serial-test.c
$ ./serial-test 
select: fd did not become writeable within 5 seconds
write: wrote 0 bytes
```

I am not a serial port wizard. I'd be happy to perform any experiment you suggest. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried `write()` without `select()`? Try to make a [mre] to find the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did first. The `select()` does not affect the result of the `write()`.

Comment: if you need to be *root* (sudo) to read `/proc/tty/driver/ttyAMA` why are you writing in it by hand (`echo hello | cat - > /dev/ttyAMA0` whose can be `echo hello > /dev/ttyAMA0`) or your program without being *root* again ?

Comment: Running my program as root does not change the result (just tried it). I can read and write `/dev/ttyAMA0` as non-root because I am in the relevant group (`dialout`). It's just the `/proc/tty/driver` directory (containing diagnostics) that is only readable by root.

Comment: @NeilForrester ok, sorry then

Comment: It's all right, I appreciate any help I can get. :)

Comment: @bruno: Possibly interesting fact: if I take your suggestion to run `echo hello > /dev/ttyAMA0`, my shell hangs. Control-C will not get me a prompt back. I have to "kill -KILL <pid>` it from another terminal.

Comment: Ah, so may be it is blocked writting? Anyway may be look at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/69721 and the link https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571 supposing it is the same on a PI3 and a PI4

Comment: Do you get _anything_ [as seen on scope] when in uart mode? What baud rate? I note 62500000 from `dmesg` [seems a bit high?]. What about cable wiring for DTR/RTS/CTS/etc? Are you sure _both_ sides clear `CRTSCTS`? What program is running on each side?

Comment: @bruno is the winner! Writing to `/dev/ttyS0` makes my scope wiggle! Post that as an answer and you get my upvote!

Comment: Your link to the raspberrypi stack exchange solved it.

Comment: regarding: `printf("select: fd did not become writeable within 5 seconds\n");` this is a significant error (and should have been output to `stderr`, not `stdout`)  After this error, the code continues as if the `select()` had been successful.  That is a logic error.  It should be exiting the program.

Comment: regarding: `int wlen;`  the function: `write()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refering to [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 (or later model)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3-or-later-model)
 :

> The miniUART is now available on /dev/ttyS0

so you have to write on `/dev/ttyS0` rather than `/dev/ttyAMA0`