# Opening USB device for communication in C

Tags: c, macos, usb

The short version. When trying to open a USB device using the open() function in the fcntl.h header, the program freezes

Now the slightly longer version. I am trying to interface with a time of flight sensor ([TeraRanger Evo 60m](https://www.terabee.com/shop/lidar-tof-range-finders/teraranger-evo-60m/)). I am working on a mac running Big Sur 11.2.1. Using `ls -l /dev/tty.*` i have located the device path to be /dev/tty.usbmodem00000000001A1.

I have taken my code and heavily simplified it to isolate the issue I'm currently facing

```
#include <fcntl.h> // open
#include <stdio.h>  // print

int main()
{
  // /dev/tty.usbmodem00000000001A1
  char *device = "/dev/tty.usbmodem00000000001A1";

  printf("Start\n");
  int fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
  if(fd < 0)
  {
    perror(device);
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Opened\n");
  return 1;
}
```

When trying to open the device, the program freezes. There is no error printed to help me debug either. I have successfully connected to and received messages from another USB device I own by only changing the device path. Yet, this sensor make the code freeze.

I may also be useful to know that using the `screen /dev/tty.usbmedem00000000001A1 115200` terminal command shows the output expected from the sensor. This means the device is properly functioning and it can be connected to but i have messed up my code somehow. I would greatly appreciate any help y'all can provide. Thank you!

Comment: What if you try to read it from console?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have received output when using the screen command  for the console

Comment: Sounds that this device is pretending to be a serial port. So you should be working with it as with serial port. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c

Comment: Try to open `/dev/cu.usbmodem00000000001A1` instead of `/dev/tty.usbmodem00000000001A1`.

Comment: Wow @Codo that fixed it! thank you! Can you explain why this is?

Comment: You have to google the details on the internet. It's an old thing from the time when modems were used. */dev/tty* is for incoming calls. So *open* waits until a call arrives, while */dev/cu* is for outgoing calls and doesn't wait.