# select() always returns 0 Serial Port (UART) vxWorks

Tags: c++, posix, vxworks

OS: vxWorks
I'm using `select()` system call to enforce timeout on serial port read functionality.
I am working on an IMU with data rate of 1000 Hz (IMU sends data every 1 ms).
The baud rate is 921600.
Every packet transfer is 36 bytes long. I calculate data transmission of 388-400 us per data transfer.
I calculated if no new bytes are received for 400 us then the packet is said to have been transferred.
The problem is as stated in the title select() always returns 0 and no data being read.
I've to use `select()` system call as in vxWorks `epoll()` is only supported for file descriptors of INET type.
Code :

```
int             return_value;
fd_set          select_fd;
struct timeval  tv;
//Run continuously till reader thread is to be executed
this->data.clear();
while (not this->exitReaderThread.load()) 
{
    try
    {
        this->readBuffer.fill(0);
        
        FD_ZERO(&select_fd);
        FD_SET(this->fd, &select_fd);
        
        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = 400;

        return_value = select(this->fd+1, &select_fd, nullptr, nullptr, &tv);
        std::cerr << "Select Return Value : " << return_value << std::endl;
        if(return_value == -1) //Error
        {
            perror("SerialPort select()");
            //TODO Log Error
            continue;
        }
        else if(return_value > 0) //Data Available
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(this->fd, &select_fd) == true)
            {
                ssize_t returnValue = ::read(this->fd, this->readBuffer.data(), this->readBuffer.size());
                if(returnValue == -1)
                {
                    //TODO Log Error
                    std::cout << "Error sending data on serial port " << this->portNumber <<". Error : " << errorToString(errno)  << std::endl;
                    continue;
                }
                this->data.append((char *)this->readBuffer.data(), returnValue);
                std::cerr << "Data Receive in progress\n";
            }
        }
        else if(return_value == 0) //No Data Available
        {
            if(this->data.empty())
            {
                continue;
            }
            std::cerr << "Data Receive Complete\n";
            this->push_receive_data_in_queue("", this->portNumber, this->data);
            this->mCallbackSerialPort(this->portNumber, this->data);
            this->data.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Code to open and configure serial port

```
this->fd = ::open("/usb2ttyS/0", O_RDWR);
if(this->fd == -1)
{
    std::cout << "Error open serial port. Error : " << errorToString(errno) << std::endl;
    return false;
}

struct termios tty;
returnValue = tcgetattr(this->fd, &tty);

tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP
                           | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON | IXOFF);
tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
tty.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);

switch(this->dataBits)
{
case 5:
    tty.c_cflag |= CS5; 
    break;
case 6:
    tty.c_cflag |= CS6; 
    break;
case 7:
    tty.c_cflag |= CS7; 
    break;
case 8 :
default:
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8; 
    break;
}

switch(this->stopBits)
{
case 2:
    tty.c_cflag |= CSTOPB; 
    break;
case 1:
default:
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; 
    break;
}

switch(this->parity)
{
case 'o':
    tty.c_cflag |= PARENB;   //enable parity
    break;
case 'e':
    tty.c_cflag |= PARENB;   //enable parity
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;  //disable odd parity, therefore-> even parity
    break;
case 'n':
default:
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // No-Parity
    break;
}

returnValue = cfsetispeed(&tty, 921600);
returnValue = cfsetospeed(&tty, 921600);

returnValue = tcsetattr(this->fd, TCSANOW, &tty);
```

---

Complete Source Code

common.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <cerrno>
#include <string>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __linux__
std::string errorToString(error_t errorNumber);
#else //For vxWorks
std::string errorToString(errno_t errorNumber);
#endif
```

common.cpp

```
#include "common.hpp"

#ifdef __linux__
std::string errorToString(error_t errorNumber)
#else
std::string errorToString(errno_t errorNumber)
#endif
{
    const std::uint16_t errorStringLength {1024};  
    char errorDataCharArray[errorStringLength];
#ifdef __linux__
    std::strncpy(errorDataCharArray, 
        ::strerror_l(errno, ::uselocale((locale_t)0)), 
            errorStringLength);
#else //For vxWOrks
    strerror_s(errorDataCharArray, errorStringLength, errno);
#endif
    std::string errorString(errorDataCharArray);
    return errorString;
}
```

communication_interface.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <array>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>

typedef struct receive_data
{
    std::string     source_ip;
    std::uint16_t   source_port;
    std::string     data;
}receive_data_t;

class CommunicationInterface
{
protected:
    static const std::uint16_t READ_BUFFER_LENGTH {1024}; 
    static const std::uint16_t WRITE_BUFFER_LENGTH {1024}; 
    std::array<std::uint8_t, READ_BUFFER_LENGTH>   readBuffer;
    std::array<std::uint8_t, WRITE_BUFFER_LENGTH>  writeBuffer;
    int                     fd {-1};
    std::uint16_t           portNumber {6666};
    std::atomic_bool        exitReaderThread {false};
    std::thread             readerThread;
    virtual void            reader(void) = 0;
public:
    using callback_ethernet_t = std::function<void(std::string ip, std::uint16_t portNumber, std::string data)>;
    using callback_serial_port_t = std::function<void(std::uint8_t portNumber, std::string data)>;
    virtual bool open(void) = 0;
    virtual bool open(std::uint16_t portNumber) = 0;
    virtual bool close(void) = 0;
    virtual bool read(void) = 0;
    virtual bool write(const std::string& ipAddress, std::uint16_t portNumber, const std::string& data) = 0;
    virtual bool write(const std::string& data) = 0;
    bool registerEthernetCallback(callback_ethernet_t callback);
    bool registerSerialPortCallback(callback_serial_port_t callback);
    
    //push the received data in the queue
    inline bool push_receive_data_in_queue(const std::string& source_ip, std::uint16_t source_port, const std::string& data)
    {
        try
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (this->receive_data_queue_mutex);
            receive_data_t receiveData = {
                .source_ip = source_ip,
                .source_port = source_port,
                .data = data
            };
            this->receive_data_queue.push(receiveData);
            return true;
        }
        catch(const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            //TODO Log error to logging module
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    //Receive data and pop the first element
    inline std::optional<receive_data_t> get_received_data_and_pop(void)
    {
        try
        {
            receive_data_t receiveData;
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (this->receive_data_queue_mutex);
            if(this->receive_data_queue.empty() == true) //Queue is empty
            {
                //TODO Log warning
                std::cout << "get_received_data_and_pop requested but queue empty\n";
                return std::nullopt;
            }
            receiveData = this->receive_data_queue.front();
            this->receive_data_queue.pop();
            return receiveData;
        }
        catch(const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            //TODO Log error to logging module
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    }
    
    //Receive data but don't pop the first element
    inline std::optional<receive_data_t> get_received_data(void)
    {
        try
        {
            receive_data_t receiveData;
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (this->receive_data_queue_mutex);
            if(this->receive_data_queue.empty() == true) //Queue is empty
            {
                //TODO Log warning
                std::cout << "get_received_data requested but queue empty\n";
                return std::nullopt;
            }
            receiveData = this->receive_data_queue.front();
            return receiveData;
        }
        catch(const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            //TODO Log error to logging module
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    }
    
    inline bool is_data_available(void)
    {
        try
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (this->receive_data_queue_mutex);
            if(this->receive_data_queue.empty() == true) //Queue is empty
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch(const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            //TODO Log error to logging module
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    CommunicationInterface(/* args */) {}
    ~CommunicationInterface() {}
protected:
    callback_ethernet_t             mCallbackEthernet;
    callback_serial_port_t          mCallbackSerialPort;
    std::queue<receive_data_t>      receive_data_queue;
    std::mutex                      receive_data_queue_mutex;
};
```

communication_interface.cpp

```
#include "communication_interface.hpp"

bool CommunicationInterface::registerEthernetCallback(callback_ethernet_t callback)
{
    try
    {
        this->mCallbackEthernet = callback;
        return true;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return false;    
}

bool CommunicationInterface::registerSerialPortCallback(callback_serial_port_t callback)
{
    try
    {
        this->mCallbackSerialPort = callback;
        return true;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return false;    
}
```

serial_port.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <thread>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include "posix_timer.hpp"
#include "communication_interface.hpp"

class SerialPort : public CommunicationInterface
{
private:
    PosixTimer              timer;
    std::string             portName;
    void                    reader(void) override;
    std::uint32_t           baudRate    {115200};
    std::uint8_t            dataBits    {8};
    std::uint8_t            stopBits    {1};
    char                    parity      {'n'};
    std::uint64_t           timer_interval {200}; //Set the timeout interval in nanoseconds
    PosixTimer              messageTimeOutTimer;
    std::string             data;
    void                    timeOutCallback(const std::any& callback_data);
public:
    SerialPort ();
    ~SerialPort ();
    bool            open(void) override;
    bool            open(std::uint16_t portNumber) override;
    bool            close(void) override;
    bool            read(void) override;
    bool            write(const std::string& ipAddress, std::uint16_t portNumber, const std::string& data) override;
    bool            write(const std::string& data) override;
    std::uint32_t   getBaudRate(void) const;
    std::uint32_t   setBaudRate(std::uint32_t baudRate);
    std::uint8_t    getDataBits(void) const;
    std::uint8_t    setDataBits(std::uint8_t dataBits);
    std::uint8_t    getStopBits(void) const;
    std::uint8_t    setStopBits(std::uint8_t stopBits);
    char            getParity(void) const;
    char            setParity(char parity);
};
```

serial_port.cpp

```
#include "serial_port.hpp"
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "common.hpp"
#include <termios.h>

SerialPort::SerialPort()
{
    this->data.reserve(4096);
    this->timer.registerCallback(std::bind(&SerialPort::timeOutCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1), this->timer_interval);
    this->timer.create();
}

SerialPort::~SerialPort()
{
    this->timer.destroy();
    if(this->fd < 0) //if port is not closed i.e. this->fd != -1 then close the port
    {
        this->close();
    }
}

void SerialPort::reader(void)
{
    int             return_value;
    fd_set          select_fd;
    struct timeval  tv;
    //Run continuously till reader thread is to be executed
    this->data.clear();
    while (not this->exitReaderThread.load()) 
    {
        try
        {
            this->readBuffer.fill(0);
            
            FD_ZERO(&select_fd);
            FD_SET(this->fd, &select_fd);
            
            tv.tv_sec = 1;
            tv.tv_usec = 0;

            return_value = select(this->fd+1, &select_fd, nullptr, nullptr, &tv);
            std::cerr << "Select Return Value : " << return_value << std::endl;
            if(return_value == -1) //Error
            {
                perror("SerialPort select()");
                //TODO Log Error
                continue;
            }
            else if(return_value > 0) //Data Available
            {
                if(FD_ISSET(this->fd, &select_fd) == true)
                {
                    ssize_t returnValue = ::read(this->fd, this->readBuffer.data(), this->readBuffer.size());
                    if(returnValue == -1)
                    {
                        //TODO Log Error
                        std::cout << "Error sending data on serial port " << this->portNumber <<". Error : " << errorToString(errno)  << std::endl;
                        continue;
                    }
                    this->data.append((char *)this->readBuffer.data(), returnValue);
                    std::cerr << "Data Receive in progress\n";
                }
            }
            else if(return_value == 0) //No Data Available
            {
                if(this->data.empty())
                {
                    continue;
                }
                std::cerr << "Data Receive Complete\n";
                this->push_receive_data_in_queue("", this->portNumber, this->data);
                this->mCallbackSerialPort(this->portNumber, this->data);
                this->data.clear();
            }
            
        }
        catch(const std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
            //TODO Log Error
        }
    }
}

void SerialPort::timeOutCallback(const std::any& callback_data)
{
    std::cout << "Callback Interval : " << this->timer_interval << std::endl;
    this->push_receive_data_in_queue("", this->portNumber, data);
    this->mCallbackSerialPort(this->portNumber, data);
    data.clear();
}

bool SerialPort::open(void)
{
    try
    {
        int returnValue;
        std::cout << "Opening Port : " << this->portName.c_str() << std::endl;
        this->fd = ::open(this->portName.c_str(), O_RDWR);
        if(this->fd == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Error open serial port. Error : " << errorToString(errno) << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        
        struct termios tty;
        returnValue = tcgetattr(this->fd, &tty);
        
        tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP
                                   | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON | IXOFF);
        tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
        tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
        tty.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
        
        switch(this->dataBits)
        {
        case 5:
            tty.c_cflag |= CS5; 
            break;
        case 6:
            tty.c_cflag |= CS6; 
            break;
        case 7:
            tty.c_cflag |= CS7; 
            break;
        case 8 :
        default:
            tty.c_cflag |= CS8; 
            break;
        }
        
        switch(this->stopBits)
        {
        case 2:
            tty.c_cflag |= CSTOPB; 
            break;
        case 1:
        default:
            tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; 
            break;
        }
        
        switch(this->parity)
        {
        case 'o':
            tty.c_cflag |= PARENB;   //enable parity
            break;
        case 'e':
            tty.c_cflag |= PARENB;   //enable parity
            tty.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;  //disable odd parity, therefore-> even parity
            break;
        case 'n':
        default:
            tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // No-Parity
            break;
        }
        
        returnValue = cfsetispeed(&tty, this->baudRate);
        returnValue = cfsetospeed(&tty, this->baudRate);
        
        returnValue = tcsetattr(this->fd, TCSANOW, &tty);
        
        return true;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

bool SerialPort::open(std::uint16_t portNumber)
{
    this->portName.clear();
    this->portNumber = portNumber;
    //TODO Currently USB-Serial Names are used. Need to be changed to PCIe-Serial Names when hardware is received
    switch(portNumber)
    {
    case 1:
        this->portName = "/usb2ttyS/0";
        break;
    case 2:
        this->portName = "/usb2ttyS/1";
        break;
    case 3:
        this->portName = "/usb2ttyS/2";
        break;
    case 4:
        this->portName = "/usb2ttyS/3";
        break;
    default:
        this->portNumber = UINT16_MAX;
        std::cout << "Invalid port number in SerialPort::open call. Port Number : " << portNumber << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return this->open();
}

bool SerialPort::close(void)
{
    try
    {
        int returnValue = ::close(this->fd);
        if(returnValue == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Error closing serial port " << this->portNumber << ". Error : " << errorToString(errno) << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        this->fd = -1;
        return true;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

bool SerialPort::read(void)
{
    try
    {
        this->exitReaderThread.store(false); //Set the tread exit event to false
        this->readerThread = std::thread(&SerialPort::reader, this);
        return true;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << '\n';
        return false;
    }
}

bool SerialPort::write(const std::string& ipAddress, std::uint16_t portNumber, const std::string& data)
{
    std::cout << "Multiple Parameter (with IP Address) write function can't be called on SerialPort class" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

std::uint32_t SerialPort::getBaudRate(void) const
{
    return this->baudRate;
}

std::uint32_t SerialPort::setBaudRate(std::uint32_t baudRate)
{
    switch(baudRate)
    {
    case 1200:
        this->baudRate = 1200; // Used for testing
        break;
    case 9600:
        this->baudRate = 9600; // Used for Meteorological sensor
        break;
    case 115200:
        this->baudRate = 115200; // Used for HCP
        break;
    case 921600:
        this->baudRate = 921600; // Used for IMU
        break;
    default:
        this->baudRate = 115200; //Default to Baud Rate 115200
        break;
    }
    return this->getBaudRate();
}

std::uint8_t SerialPort::getDataBits(void) const
{
    return this->dataBits;
}

std::uint8_t SerialPort::setDataBits(std::uint8_t dataBits)
{
    switch(dataBits)
    {
    case 7:// [[fallthrough]];
    case 8:
        this->dataBits = dataBits;
        break;
    default:
        this->dataBits = 8; //Default to 1 Data Bit
        break;
    }
    return this->getDataBits();
}

std::uint8_t SerialPort::getStopBits(void) const
{
    return this->stopBits;
}

std::uint8_t SerialPort::setStopBits(std::uint8_t stopBits)
{
    switch(stopBits)
    {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        this->stopBits = stopBits;
        break;
    default:
        this->stopBits = 1; //Default to 1 Stop Bit
        break;
    }
    return this->getStopBits();
}

char SerialPort::getParity(void) const
{
    return this->parity;
}

char SerialPort::setParity(char parity)
{
    switch(parity)
    {
    case 'n':
    case 'o':
    case 'e':
        this->parity = parity;
        break;
    default:
        this->parity = 'n'; //Default to None parity 
        break;
    }
    return this->getParity();
}

bool SerialPort::write(const std::string& data)
{
    try
    {
        ssize_t returnValue = ::write(this->fd, data.c_str(), data.length());
        if(returnValue == -1)
        {
            //Log error
            std::cout << "Error sending data on serial port " << this->portNumber <<". Error : " << errorToString(errno)  << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

The value of file descriptor (this->fd) is 4.
I have run the program several times and the value of file descriptor is always 4.

Comment: whats the value of this->fd? Im asking because select checks only descriptors < 1024

Comment: The code seems correct, but the opening of `fd` is missing; some options might be important. See e.g. <https://stackoverflow.com/a/38318768/1788851>

Comment: @EdouardThiel I've added code to open and configure serial port.

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen I will have to check but their are no more than 5 `open()` system call but I will check and update.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Questions like what `this->fd` is wouldn't be necessary then.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've added complete minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @EdouardThiel I've added complete minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen  I've added complete minimal reproducible example.

Comment: is this a copy paste error, the 2 in select? return_value = select(2, &select_fd, nullptr, nullptr, &tv);

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen Its a copy paste error. I've fixed it.

Comment: Extract a [mcve]. Remove stuff that isn't necessary to demo the problem. I"m not going to wade through `#ifdef __linux__` stuff in multiple files to filter that out myself. That's your job and you should have done it before even posting here, because it improves your focus on the problem.