Enable UART2 of LX2160A in Linux
I tried to use UART serial port in user-application on SoC running Linux on a LX2160ARDB board.
There are 2 UART ports using PL011 UART hardware (UART1, UART2).
After Linux boots up, I can find the device nodes of the 2 UART ports (/dev/ttyAMA0, /dev/ttyAMA1).
The application does open(/dev/ttyAMAx) and write() to the device file.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main( void )
{
    int fd;

    int retn;
    int buf[10] = "write...\n";

    /* Open UART */
    fd = open( "/dev/ttyAMA1", O_RDWR );
    if( fd < 0 )
    {
        perror("Open /dev/ttyAMA1 error!");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Opening /dev/ttyAMA1 -> success!\n");

    /* Write Operation - Tx start */
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        retn = write( fd, buf, 10 );
        if( retn < 0 )
            printf("Write() failed... retn=%d\n");
        else
            printf("Write() succeeded! retn=%d\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

    /* Close UART */
    printf("Closing /dev/ttyAMA1\n");
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

I connected SoC's UART port and my laptop by RS232 cable and ran the application, and check the signal by terminal emulator.
when trying /dev/ttyAMA0 (UART1), I can see the signal ("write...\n" string) on terminal emulator connected to UART1 port, but when trying /dev/ttyAMA1 (UART2), I can't see the signal ("write...\n" string) on terminal emulator connected to UART2 port and the application process does not terminate.
( In both case, open(), write() function returned valid value. )
I checked the Control Register value of each UART by accessing /dev/mem, and found UART2's ENABLE bit is not set to 1 while UART1's is set to 1.
(the same goes for registers related to setting baud rate and data-bit.)
...
int main( void )
{
...
    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
...
    /* mmap() UART, x can be 1 or 2 */
    baseaddr = mmap(0,
                    UARTx_SIZE,
                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_SHARED,
                    fd,
                    UARTx_BASE);
    if( baseaddr == NULL )
    {
        perror("mmap() error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("mmap succeeded!\n");

    /* set pointer of UART Control Register */
    uartcr = ( uint32_t * )( baseaddr + UARTCR_OFFSET );
    
    /* check value of Control Register */
    printf("Current UARTCR value: %#010x\n", *( uartcr ));

...
}

----------
[RESULT]

UART1: Current UARTCR value: 0x00000b01 ( bit[0] is 1 )
UART2: Current UARTCR value: 0x00000300 ( bit[0] is 0 )

UARTCR's bit[0] is UARTEN bit


UART1 is selected for console, so it seems that Bootloader configure UART1 and set ENABLE bit but does not configure UART2.
My question is:
How to set UART2's ENABLE bit from user application in Linux?
(more precisely, how to invoke initialization of UART2, not using /dev/mem)
can't we set ENABLE bit of UART controller on Linux? only can in Bootloader?
I've searched some driver codes (amba-pl011.c etc.), but I couldn't understand the layer for serial device..
Additional materials

I tried termios for UART2 settings. but can't see Tx string ("Hello World!\n\r").
terminal emulator (Tera Term) settings I used are "115200 baud rate, 8-bit data bit, no parity, 1-bit stop bit, no hardware flow control"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    int fd, ret;
    char tx_buf[] = "Hello World!\n\r";
    structt termios options;

    /* open UART */
    fd = open( "/dev/ttyAMA1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
    if( fd < 0 )
    {
        printf("ERROR open /dev/ttyAMA1\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    /* configure UART */
    tcgetattr( fd, &options );
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    options.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG );
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    options.c_iflag &= ~( ICRNL | IXON );
    cfsetispeed( &options, B115200 );
    cfsetospeed( &options, B115200 );
    options.c_cflag |= ( CLOCAL | CREAD );
    tcflush( fd, TCIFLUSH );
    tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &options );

    /* test UART */
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        ret = write( fd, tx_buf, sizeof(tx_buf) );
        if( ret != sizeof(tx_buf) )
            printf("ERROR write, ret=%d\n\r", ret);
        printf("write successfully, ret=%d\n\r", ret);
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("Tx Test END!\n\r");

    /* close UART */
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}


You need to know what termios means in Unix systems. UART devices require a lot of settings (via IOCTLs) before one can use them.

"How to set UART2's ENABLE bit from user application in Linux?" _ No, you don't manipulate device registers from userspace that already have a kernel driver. Your assumptions are incorrect. Review the kernel boot log for a possible failed UART2 initialization. Your system may be improperly configured.

@0andriy I also tried termios, I did tcgetattr(), established settings (no parity bit, baud rate, data bits etc.) and finally tcsetattr() but UART hardware's registers did not change (remain inactive, baud rate not set etc.). This use of termios is incorrect?

@sawdust I can see some log related to UART in kernel boot log. "Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver" , "21d0000,serial: ttyAMA1 at MMIO 0x21d0000 (irq = 27, base_baud = 0) is a SBSA" ... I cannot find UART initialization fail log. How does the log look if UART initialization fails?

The driver could be silent, and only report the startup failure as an errno value for an open() syscall. BTW your description of the problem is inadequate. What does "trying /dev/ttyAMA1(UART2), the signal is not detected" mean? How are you "trying"? What "signal" are you referring to? Why haven't you posted the code of this "application"? Since you made a correction to the device name for the 2nd serial terminal in your post, did you perform this same correction in your "application"?

@sawdust I'll add the code of application. I wrote wrong device name(ttyAMA1, ttyAMA2) in post before editing, but in application I used right device name(ttyAMA0, ttyAMA1) even before I wrote this post first time. sorry for confusing.

The difference you see with Enable bits is simple. You wrote that /dev/ttyAMA0 is the system console, therefore its Linux driver (and not the "Bootloader") enabled UART1.  When you try to examine the control registers, there is no "application" using /dev/ttyAMA1, so UART2 is idle as expected. Then you incorrectly assume that this non-enabled state to be the reason for your "application" problems. Wrong assumption!

Your "application" treats /dev/ttyAMA1 as if it was a regular file instead of the serial terminal that it represents. Study Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems. Because your "application" neglects to properly initialize the serial terminal, you cannot expect reliable communication with another port. Both ends of a serial link must use the same configuration. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c/38318768#38318768 for a example of working code.

Do you have the stty command? If so, run stty -aF /dev/ttyAMA1 to check the current terminal settings, including the speed. (You may need to use sudo.)

@IanAbbott I tried stty -aF /dev/ttyAMAx (x=0,1) and result is UART1: speed 115200 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0; intr=^C .. and so on and UART2: speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0; intr = ^C .. and so on. I think the only difference is rows 24; columns 80 for UART1 and rows 0; columns 0 for UART2.

@sawdust If I start the application which open() and write() for a while to the /dev/ttyAMA1 in background, and check Control Register of UART2, then should I be able to see UARTEN bit is set to 1? I did so, but UART2's Enable bit still 0.. and I also tried termios method, but can't see the Tx string. I'll attach termios try code.

You wrote that "There are 2 UART ports using PL011 UART hardware", but the syslog reports that the configuration is ttyAMA1 at MMIO 0x21d0000 (irq = 27, base_baud = 0) is a SBSA. The amba-pl011.c driver supports both the PL011 and SBSA devices, but the Enable bit of the CR is only manipulated for the PL011 and not the SBSA. So which kind of UART do you really have? Is the correct driver installed for this UART?

rows and columns won't matter. Things that could matter are the modem control and flow control options, and the clocal option when opening.

The specification of the SBSA UART registers can be found in Appendix B of Arm® Server Base System Architecture 6.0 Platform Design Document. The CR register does not exist. I suppose it is possible that the UART really could be a full PL011 but is described incorrectly as an SBSA UART in the devicetree or ACPI settings, but that would seem unlikely.

The LX2160A that the OP uses does have two PL011 UARTs, but for whatever reason, the convention is to use the "simpler" SBSA Linux driver. NXP Tech Support only mentions how to use "firmware" (?) to configure UART1 as the console and change the baudrate, and completely ignores the question about UART2. Seems like NXP may not officially support a second UART in Linux?

That seems right. I was able to see that the compatible property of the uart nodes is set to "arm,sbsa-uart","arm,pl011" in the devicetree for the LX2160A(fsl-lx2160a.dtsi). I'll look into the materials which you provided. Thanks.

Three years ago someone tried to fix the compatible string of LX2160A UART in fsl-lx2160a.dtsi to use the PL011 driver instead of the SBSA one, could not get it to work, and gave up. "Although the hardware
is actually compatible with the pl011, it would be better for us to
follow the newer SBSA standard to leave advanced configuration to
firmware and just expose the simple standard interface to OS."

You should change PBI (Pre-boot loader initialization) for proper configuring CCSR of UART (QorIQ LX2160A Reference Manual, chapter 8 Service Proccesor). Or you can simply change CCSR in U-boot or even Linux console. When i was trying to make UART2 working I read registers from UART1 and copy them to UART2 by bash script. (QorIQ LX2160A Reference Manual, chapter 29 UART)
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

 # enable uart2
 ccsr -w 0x21d0024 0x5e
 ccsr -w 0x21d0028 0x3c
 ccsr -w 0x21d002c 0x70
 ccsr -w 0x21d0030 0xb01
 ccsr -w 0x21d003c 0x50

 # same with devmem2, but I recommend to use ccsr command
 devmem 0x21d0024 w 0x5e
 devmem 0x21d0028 w 0x3c
 devmem 0x21d002c w 0x70
 devmem 0x21d0030 w 0xb01
 devmem 0x21d003c w 0x50

You can also change ccsr from U-boot console with md/mw commands.
=> md 21c0000
021c0000: 00000062 00000000 00000000 00000000    b...............
021c0010: 00000000 00000000 0000013e 00000000    ........>.......
021c0020: 00000000 0000005e 0000003c 00000070    ....^...<...p...
021c0030: 00000b01 00000012 00000050 00000002    ........P.......
021c0040: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021c0050: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021c0060: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021c0070: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021c0080: 00000000 00000009 00000000 00000000    ................
021c0090: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021c00a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021c00b0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021c00c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021c00d0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021c00e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021c00f0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
=> md 21d0000
021d0000: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d0010: 00000000 00000000 00000196 00000000    ................
021d0020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d0030: 00000300 00000012 00000000 00000002    ................
021d0040: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d0050: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d0060: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d0070: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d0080: 00000000 00000009 00000000 00000000    ................
021d0090: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d00a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d00b0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d00c0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d00d0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d00e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
021d00f0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................

If you would to like to make persistent changes you should refer to PBI ccsr data configuration.
